# C#: How to print a unicode string to console?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, console

How do I print out the value of a unicode `String` in C# to the console?

```
byte[] unicodeBytes = new byte[] 
    {0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 
     0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x70, 0x63, 
     0x61, 0x70};

string unicodeString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);

Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);
```

What I get for the above is "?????????"

However, I see the following in the autos and local window when in debug mode for the value of unicodeString which is what I wanted to display.

"慒䑷瑡彡〵〶ㅟ⸷慣�"

How do I print out the correct result to the console as what the autos and local window for debugging demonstrated?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app

Comment: It is an 8-bit encoding, not Unicode.  Could be a lot of them (well, about all of them), but Encoding.ASCII.GetString() will work fine since they are all ASCII codes.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect these bytes are really in `UTF8`, not in `UTF16` as you supposed.

See, if you change your code to:

```
byte[] unicodeBytes = new byte[] 
    {0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61, 
     0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x70, 0x63, 
     0x61, 0x70};

string unicodeString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unicodeBytes);

Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);
```

You'll get the output:

> application/pcap

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following answer:
[c# unicode string output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055659/c-sharp-unicode-string-output)

In short:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Then change the console font to Lucida Console, which supports unicode characters.