# C# Unicode string output

Tags: .net, unicode, c#-4.0

I have a function to convert a string to a Unicode string:

```
private string UnicodeString(string text)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));
}
```

But when I am calling this function the output result is wrong. It looks like my function is not working.

`Console.WriteLine(UnicodeString("добры дзень"))` printing on console just questions like that: `????? ????`

Is there a way to say to console to display it correct?

**UPDATE**

It looks like the problem not in Unicode. I think maybe it is displaying question marks because I am not having the correct locale in the system (Windows 7)?

Is there a way to make it work without changing locale?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First, change the output encoding to UTF8:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("добры дзень");
```

Now you'll still see question marks. The reason is that the *default console's font doesn't support Cyrillic letters*. Change the font of the console:

[image]

If you're lucky, you should find a different font with Unicode support:

[image]

Change the font, and you should be able to see your text:

[image]

In the general case, if you want to display all Unicode characters reliably, the Console is probably not right for you. See also: [C# console font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971684/c-console-font/3971750#3971750) (the comments are interesting too)

Answer (score 1):

```
private string UnicodeString(string text)
{
    return text;
}
```

The string `text` is already in Unicode. All internal C# strings are Unicode. When you convert it to ASCII you lose characters. That is why you get ????? ????.

Answer (score 0):

Just do plain simple `Console.WriteLine("добры дзень");` no need for any conversion.

Comment: It was like that initially, it won't work, the output just question marks.

Comment: It's probably the Console object printing in ASCII then.

Try changing the OutputEncoding property e.g. Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;