# Converter into euro c#

Tags: c#, formatting, currency

I have to convert from Lei into euro by using string formatting for currency.
My method is:

```
public static void ConvertFromRonEur()
    {
        //string amount = string.Format("{0:C}");
        double result;
        Console.WriteLine("Lei: ");
        double quantity;
        double euro = 0.22D;
        quantity = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        result = quantity * euro;
        Console.WriteLine(("{0:C} Euro"), result);
    }
```

When I run the result is:

```
  Lei:
  10
  $2,20 Euro
```

How can I have only the `2,20` Euro result, but to use the string formatting currency? Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You need to specify the Culture, to a String.Format

Something like

```
//use any european culture
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"); 
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C} Euro", result));
```

An alternative

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("€{0:N2} Euro", result));
```

Format to 2 decimal places (prefixed by €)

Comment: which method? the first or second?

Comment: to both of them. the first show me: "2.20 ? Euro" and the second "? 2.20 Euro".

Comment: hmm, that's odd - what's your native culture? i.e - where are you

Comment: That's a separate issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055659/c-sharp-unicode-string-output

Comment: the link posted by @Pluto should help

Comment: I've changed in all fonts found in properties but it displays the same question mark.

Answer (score 2):

From: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> "C" or "c" : Currency      Result: A currency value. Supported by: All
>   numeric types. Precision specifier: Number of decimal digits. Default
>   precision specifier: Defined by
>   NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits.
>
> More information: The Currency ("C") Format Specifier.

```
123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46  
123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €  
123.456 ("C", ja-JP) -> ¥123  
-123.456 ("C3", en-US) -> ($123.456)  
-123.456 ("C3", fr-FR) -> -123,456 €  
-123.456 ("C3", ja-JP) -> -¥123.456
```