# Is it possible to print Bengali language with C in console?

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to print Bengali Language with C in console? If it can be done, how can I do it?

I tried:

```
wprintf (L"Character: %lc %lc \n", L'ঈ', 2440);
```

This does not work. It just shows an unknown symbol. What is the best formula for working with UTF-8 format data in console? If it is possible with C++, I want to know that.

Comment: Well, that depends on the capabilities of your terminal. You might need to select the correct locale settings.

Comment: How i will select correct locale settings for Terminal ? :)

Comment: There's no standard way, depends on OS mostly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a language & display it is very much an OS dependent task and below are few generic possible ways to do it.

On linux :

1. Set [Locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale),

In your case it should be : `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'bn_IN.utf8');`

Refer : (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/displaying-hindi-in-linux-command-prompt-terminal-4175448642/)

2. Download appropriate font & install in your system.
   Check your : `cd /usr/share/fonts/` for the font.
   edit your .bashrc file and add your font like this:

   `export LANG=bn_IN.UTF-8`

   (Side effect your whole os may start using this font if it supports).

On Windows :

[Necessary criteria for fonts to be available in a command window](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247815)

[How to print a unicode string to console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638936/c-how-to-print-a-unicode-string-to-console)

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751827/displaying-arabic-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application/21753872#21753872)

Note : Your Terminal must support Unicode for any of this to work.

Comment: Good to know it helped :)