# WideCharToMultiByte problem

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, widechar

I have the lovely functions from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329718/utfcpp-and-win32-wide-api), which work fine if I do this:

```
wstring temp;
wcin >> temp;

string whatever( toUTF8(getSomeWString()) );

// store whatever, copy, but do not use it as UTF8 (see below)

wcout << toUTF16(whatever) << endl;
```

The original form is reproduced, but the in between form often contains extra characters. If I enter for example `àçé` as the input, and add a `cout << whatever` statement, i'll get `┬à┬ç┬é` as output.

Can I still use this string to compare to others, procured from an ASCII source? Or asked differently: if I would output `┬à┬ç┬é` through the UTF8 cout in linux, would it read `àçé`? Is the byte content of a string `àçé`, read in UTF8 linux by cin, exactly the same as what the Win32 API gets me?

Thanks!

PS: the reason I'm asking is because I need to use the string a lot to compare to other read values (comparing and concatenating...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by me saying that it appears that there is simply **no** way to output UTF-8 text to the console in Windows via `cout` (assuming you compile with Visual Studio).
What you can do however for your tests is to output your UTF-8 text via the Win32 API fn `WriteConsoleA`:

```
if(!SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)) { // 65001
    cerr << "Failed to set console output mode!\n";
    return 1;
}
HANDLE const consout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD nNumberOfCharsWritten;
const char* utf8 = "Umlaut AE = \xC3\x84 / ue = \xC3\xBC \n";
if(!WriteConsoleA(consout, utf8, strlen(utf8), &nNumberOfCharsWritten, NULL)) {
    DWORD const err = GetLastError();
    cerr << "WriteConsole failed with << " << err << "!\n";
    return 1;
}
```

This should output:
`Umlaut AE = Ä / ue = ü` if you set your console (cmd.exe) to use the Lucida Console font.

As for your question (taken from your comment) if

> a win23 API converted string is the
>   same as a raw UTF8 (linux) string

I will say yes: Given a Unicode character sequence, it's UTF-16 (Windows wchar_t) representation converted to a UTF-8 (char) representation via the `WideCharToMultiByte` function will always yield the same byte sequence.

Comment: If you are using `WriteConsole` anyway, you can also use `WriteConsoleW` to write the UTF-16 string directly, eliminating the necessity for `SetConsoleOutputCP`.

Comment: @Philipp - Yes, first converting from utf16 to utf8 and then using WriteConsoleA makes little sense. If the strings in the (test-)app are already utf8 though, it might still make sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert the string to a UTF 16 it is a 16 byte wide character, you can't compare it to the ASCII values because they aren't 16 byte values.  You have to convert them to compare, or write a specialized comparision to ASCII function.

I doubt the UTF8 cout in linux would produce the same correct output unless it were regular ASCII values, as UTF8 [UTF-8 encoding forms are binary-compatible with ASCII for code points below 128,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)  and I assume UTF16 comes after UTF8 in a simliar fashion.

The good news is there are many [converters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/utfConvert.aspx) out there written to convert these strings to different character sets.

Comment: I know about conversions (I use them in the previous question I linked to, and I'm converting exactly because I need to perform comparisons), and I'm trying to establish if a win23 API converted string is the same as a raw UTF8 (linux) string. `cout` on linux outputs the characters nicely, that's why it uses UTF8 in the first place (well, probably lots of other reasons too). The thing is, I don't know if the `┬à┬ç┬é` string is also present in a raw UTF8 string.