# How to output utf8 encoded characters normally in c/c++ console application?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8

Here's what I'm getting now by `wprintf`:

```
1胩?鳧?1敬爄汯?瑳瑡獵猆慴畴??
```

Is utf8 just not supported by windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [utfcpp and Win32 wide API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329718/utfcpp-and-win32-wide-api)

Answer (score 6):

No, Windows doesn't support printing UTF-8 to the console.

When Windows says "Unicode", it means UTF-16.  You need to use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16.  Something like this:

```
char* text = "My UTF-8 text\n";
int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, text, -1, 0, 0);
wchar_t *unicode_text = new wchar_t[len];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, text, -1, unicode_text, len);
wprintf(L"%s", unicode_text);
```

Comment: @Alan: No, they are both methods of encoding Unicode text into bytes.  UTF-16 uses at least 16 bits per character, whereas UTF-8 will use 8 bits per character for most Western characters.  UTF-8 is popular on the web and on operating systems other than Windows, while Windows uses UTF-16.  They do the same job, in different ways.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2 for full details.

Answer (score 1):

`wprintf` supposed to receive a UTF-16 encoded string. Use the following for conversion:

Use `MultiByteToWideChar` with `CP_UTF8` codepage to do the conversion. (and don't do blind casting from `char*` into `wchar_t*`).

Comment: It is supposed to receive UTF-16 only on Windows (which is actually against the standard, cause UTF-16 is a variable length encoding). Most other platforms expect UTF-32.