# How to implement C++ asian characters for cross platform?

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to implement some string processing for Japanese in `C++` (my system is `OSX`). That seems much harder than it sounds. I read a lot, but still have problems with basic things.

I want my code to compile and run on other machines too. That seems to exclude the `wchar_t data type`, by what I read so far.

- In which `datatype` should I represent my Japanese character then?
- If I use char, I get an error that the data doesn't fit into the `char-data type`. What other datatype should I use then?
- Is there any acceptable way of processing `wide-char` languages with `standard c++` without pitfalls or will I always create a system depend piece of code if I stick to standard `c++`?

Comment: Let´s start with the encoding. Dou you want UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 ?

Comment: Addition: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/ wchar_t is there in C++, but that alone won´t help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform strings (and Unicode) in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169948/cross-platform-strings-and-unicode-in-c)

Comment: Could be [Shift-JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) as well.

Comment: I want to use UTF-16 and have the possibility to address a single character. If I use a std::string a single Japanese character has length 3 what makes it really complicated to work with them.

Comment: @user1091534 If you stick to just normal Japanese character UTF-16 will always use a single code unit, but things like emoji or a Japanese version of zalgo text will use more than just a single UTF-16 code unit per character. Whatever it is you're doing, solving those problems will solve any issues UTF-8's three bytes per normal Japanese character problem too. If you rely on UTF-16 acting like a 'fixed width' encoding then your code will probably be broken.

Comment: Forget about std::string. Doing any sensible processing with a variable length encoding is a huge pain. Japanese is all in the basic multilingual plane, so two-char strings are just right.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Unfortunately Unicode is fundamentally variable width. The only ways to robustly handle characters encoded in Unicode as fixed width are quite expensive. E.g.: using a dynamic allocation for possibly every single character.

Comment: UTF-32 isn't :) Compound characters aren't a concern in Japanese. Let's have a glyph vs. codepoint flame war; those are fun.

Comment: I thought that UTF-8 was pretty much standard.

Comment: For wire formats - indeed it is. For string processing, it's - see above - a pain.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Yep, code points aren't characters. I can't process Japanese zalgo text (e.g., キ͙̜͉̝̱͙̲̇ͦテ̛̻̤̣͔̘̺̜͆̅̏͋̚ィ̰͍͚̪͎̂̋ͦ・͓̤͕͔̘̀ホ̖̘̹̟̅͌ͫ̌̓ワ͚͈̭̲̓͗ͩ̈́イ̗̼͌̈͆ͤ̈́ト) as fixed width even using UTF-32.

Comment: That isn't legal Japanese :)

Comment: That doesn't mean users won't use it or that whatever failures occur in a program that pretends UTF-32 can be treated as fixed width characters are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not `wchar_t` and `wstring`? Yes, it's 4 bytes on some platforms and 2 bytes on others; still, it has the advantage of having a bunch of string processing RTL routines built around it. Cocoa's NSString/CFString is 2 bytes per character (like wchar_t on Windows), but it's extremely unportable.

You'd have to be careful around persistence and wire formats - make sure they don't depend on the size of wchar_t.

Depends, really, on what's your optimization priority. If you have intense processing (parsing, etc), go with wchar_t. If you'd rather interact smoothly with the host system, opt for whatever format matches the assumptions of the host OS.

Redefining `wchar_t` to be two bytes is an option, too. It's `-fshort-wchar` with GCC. You'll lose the whole body of wcs* RTL and a good portion of STL, but there will be less codepage translation when interacting with the host system. It happens so that both big-name mobile platforms out there (one fruit-themed, one robot-themed) happen to have two byte strings as their native format, but 4 byte wchar_t by default. `-fshort-wchar` works on both, I've tried.

Here's a handy summary of desktop and mobile platforms:

- **Windows, Windows Phone, Windows RT, Windows CE**: wchar_t is **2** bytes, OS uses UTF-16
- **Vanilla desktop Linux**: wchar_t is **4** bytes, OS uses UTF-8, various frameworks may use who knows what (Qt, notably, uses UTF-16)
- **MacOS X, iOS**: wchar_t is **4** bytes, OS uses UTF-16, userland comes with a alternative 2-byte-based string RTL
- **Android**: wchar_t is **4** bytes, OS uses UTF-8, but the layer of interaction with Java uses UTF-16
- **Samsung bada**: wchar_t is **2** bytes, the userland API uses UTF-16, POSIX layer is severely crippled anyway so who cares

Answer (score 1):

> - In which datatype should I represent my Japanese character then?

The representation you should use depends on what you want to do. There's `char32_t` which can hold entire codepoints, but that doesn't necessarily solve your issues.

> - If I use `char`, I get an error that the data doesn't fit into the char-data type. What other datatype should I use then?

You absolutely can store Japanese data in `char` using the right encoding. For example UTF-8 is very common, and is the default on OS X. The following code works on OS X with clang and linux with gcc. It also works on Windows if the output is redirected to a text file (and using a bit of trickery to wring UTF-8 string literal out of VC++).

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "キティ・ホワイト\n";
}
```

Other possibilities are 16 bit integral types (UTF-16 and UCS-2 encodings), 32-bit integral types (UCS-4/UTF-32), custom type for holding complete 'characters' in your system (using either dynamic allocation or a limit on combining codepoints, or some other scheme).

> - Is there any acceptable way of processing wide-char languages with standard c++ without pitfalls or will I always create a system depend piece of code if I stick to standard c++?

Whatever this unspecified 'processing' is, if it can be done anywhere then there's a way to do it in standard, portable c++. Depending on what you need, you might want to use a library like ICU, and your choice of library might indicate what representation you use for the text. ICU, for example, adapts to different encodings, but I believe is natively UTF-16.