# conversion from char* to wchar_t

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to convert from char* to wchar.
Here is how i am doing.

```
char * retrunValue= getData();
size_t origsize = strlen(returnValue) + 1;
const size_t newsize = 200;
size_t convertedChars = 0;
wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, returnValue, _TRUNCATE);
wcscat_s(wcstring, L" (wchar_t *)");
```

getData() function returns a char* value for example "C:/Documents and Settings"
when i tried to print the converted value "wcstring": the value is not correct: it is something like this "C:/Documen9" or something garbage.
1- Please tell me is it safe to convert from char* to wchar in this way, as i am doing
2- How can i get the original value as returned by getData() function

Thanks, 
Regards

UPDATE:

```
size_t origsize = strlen(returnValue) + 1;
const size_t newsize = 200;
size_t convertedChars = 0;
wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
wsprintf(wcstring, newsize, L"%S (wchar_t *)", returnValue);
```

added this but it says.
"argument of type "size_t is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" "

Comment: See here for a nice function by me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3329718/256138

Answer (score 5):

```
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, newsize, returnValue, _TRUNCATE);
                                      ^^^
```

You're passing the wrong size.

Comment: Thanks i tried.                                                           wcstring value is 0x023bf9e8 "C:\DocumÈ (wchar_t *)" and returnvalue is 0x023bf890 "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ. While my original value c:/documents and settings. i dnt know why my returned value is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `mbstowcs()` for such conversions unless the `char*` really points to a multibyte string (not every `char` string is a multibyte string!). It might break when using `char` values above 127 (e.g. umlauts and other special characters).

As you'd like to concat another string anyway, just use `wsprintf()`:

```
// Visual Studio
wsprintf(wcstring, newsize, L"%S (wchar_t *)", returnValue);

// GCC
wsprintf(wcstring, newsize, L"%ls (wchar_t *)", returnValue);
```