# Does Visual Studio 2010 Supports C++ Source Code in Unicode with Unicode Char in String Literal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode-string

I want to directly embed non-ASCII Unicode characters in string literals and use them in *printf*.  This implies my source codes must be saved in utf-8 or utf-16.  Visual Studio 2010 does support editing and saving C++ source files in either format.  But when compiled & executed, it does not produce the correct unicode characters.  Does the compiler support string literals with unicode characters embedded?

e.g.

```
wprintf(L" chinese characters:中文字\n"); the trailing chinese characters cannot be displayed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [utfcpp and Win32 wide API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329718/utfcpp-and-win32-wide-api)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Chinese version of Windows to test with, so this is complete speculation.

The console and file output functions are aware that files are not coded in UTF-16, so they attempt to convert the characters to a code page before output. Just as the default locale is "C" rather than anything based on your system settings, so too the default code page is probably an inappropriate one that does not include Chinese characters.

There is a function [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the code page for the console. It is not clear if this function changes the code page used by the actual console window, or if it only affects conversions from Unicode within the program.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to test wide literals is to skip the formatting part of `printf`, and give your string straight to the OS: `WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L" chinese characters:中文字", ...`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that #pragma setlocale may be what you need.