# _O_WTEXT, _O_U16TEXT, _O_U8TEXT - are these modes possible in mingw compiler, are there any workarounds?

Tags: c++, unicode, console, mingw

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
  wprintf(L"\x043a\x043e\x0448\x043a\x0430 \x65e5\x672c\x56fd\n");
  return 0;
}
```

returns error at compilation: `_O_U16TEXT was not declared in this scope`

Is this a show-stopper with this compiler ?

Comment: I suppose you're following the instructions here: [Conventional wisdom is retarded, aka What the @#%&* is _O_U16TEXT?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx) The problem is that all of this is part of Microsoft's C run-time library, and a relatively recent version of it at that. Unless whatever comes bundled with MinGW duplicates this functionality exactly, you probably are out of luck.

Comment: With MingW, you may need to define macros like `WINVER` and `__MSVCRT_VERSION__` to sufficiently high values to enable certain features. Search the header files for the symbols you want and check the ambient `#if` clause. (I made a test for your question yesterday, but sadly I've deleted it since.)

Comment: I have the stock install of MinGW g++ 4.8.1 and it works for me so maybe it's not a problem with newer versions.  Of course I have lucinda console as my command prompt font...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's a simple workaround: just use values of these constants instead of their names. For example, `_O_U16TEXT` is `0x00020000` and `_O_U8TEXT` is `0x00040000`.

I've just confirmed that it works with `_setmode` using g++ 4.8.1 on Windows 10:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000); // _O_U16TEXT
    std::wcout << L"Русский текст\n";
}
```

Comment: Or just MinGW-w64, the much better mingw fork

Comment: And `_O_WTEXT` ? Which was in the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

With a higher g++ version (I used 12.2.0), `#include <fcntl.h>`  contains macros like `_O_U16TEXT`, `_O_WTEXT`, and `_O_BINARY`.

Here's the whole `<fctl.h>` file. You can see all `macros` and their `values` in it.

```
    #include <crtdefs.h>
    
    #include <io.h>
    
    #ifndef _INC_FCNTL
    #define _INC_FCNTL
    
    #define _O_RDONLY 0x0000
    #define _O_WRONLY 0x0001
    #define _O_RDWR 0x0002
    #define _O_APPEND 0x0008
    #define _O_CREAT 0x0100
    #define _O_TRUNC 0x0200
    #define _O_EXCL 0x0400
    #define _O_TEXT 0x4000
    #define _O_BINARY 0x8000
    #define _O_WTEXT 0x10000
    #define _O_U16TEXT 0x20000
    #define _O_U8TEXT 0x40000
    #define _O_ACCMODE (_O_RDONLY|_O_WRONLY|_O_RDWR)
    
    #define _O_RAW _O_BINARY
    #define _O_NOINHERIT 0x0080
    #define _O_TEMPORARY 0x0040
    #define _O_SHORT_LIVED 0x1000
    
    #define _O_SEQUENTIAL 0x0020
    #define _O_RANDOM 0x0010
    
    #if !defined(NO_OLDNAMES) || defined(_POSIX)
    #define O_RDONLY _O_RDONLY
    #define O_WRONLY _O_WRONLY
    #define O_RDWR _O_RDWR
    #define O_APPEND _O_APPEND
    #define O_CREAT _O_CREAT
    #define O_TRUNC _O_TRUNC
    #define O_EXCL _O_EXCL
    #define O_TEXT _O_TEXT
    #define O_BINARY _O_BINARY
    #define O_RAW _O_BINARY
    #define O_TEMPORARY _O_TEMPORARY
    #define O_NOINHERIT _O_NOINHERIT
    #define O_SEQUENTIAL _O_SEQUENTIAL
    #define O_RANDOM _O_RANDOM
    #define O_ACCMODE _O_ACCMODE
    #endif
    #endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't even bother with it.

Your user needs to set the font of his console to a unicode one (Lucida Console for example), or else it won't display anything. If you're targeting East Asia, where the default font is unicode aware, it'll display fine, but in Europe, you have to change the font manually.

User's won't change their console font because you write it in the readme. They won't even read the readme, they'll just see that it displays garbage, and they will think the program doesn't work.

Also, it's a farly new function VS 2005, so you need to link the VS 2005 redistributeable, msvcr50.dll, or newer (mingw link to msvcrt.dll by default). If you don't do this, the text, won't be displayed at all.

And I think a simple pipe will kill your new and shiny unicode text. Let's say your exe named a.exe. I'm pretty sure, that `a.exe | more` will NOT display unicode text.

Comment: Not sure how seven years (at time of your writing; ten now) counts as "fairly new".

Comment: That's not entirely right. Your user already may have the font that includes all the characters needed. For example, Cyrillic fonts are pretty widespread today. I think that my example from the accepted answer _should_ show the proper glyphs on any recent Windows version.

Comment: When the stream points to a pipe or file, these flags set the byte encoding to UTF-8 or UTF-16LE. You can configure cygwin's `more` to read UTF-8, and some Windows-native software consumes UTF-16. The Win32 console is native Unicode, so it would make sense for these flags to do nothing when the stream is a console. But actually it seems that characters outside the code page are mapped to `?` if you don't set one of these flags (it doesn't matter which one). I think setting them is harmless; at worst you'll see `▯` instead of `?`.