# Output unicode wchar_t character

Tags: c, unicode, mingw

Just trying to output this unicode character `☒` in C using MinGW. I first put it on a buffer using `swprintf`, and then write it to the stdout using `wprintf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    wchar_t buffer[50];
    wchar_t c = L'☒';

    swprintf(buffer, L"The character is: %c.", c);
    wprintf(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The output under Windows 8 is:

> The character is: .

Other characters such as `Ɣ` doesn't work neither.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `swprintf` has a size as the second parameter. You also have to include `wchar.h` standard header.

Comment: You're right, but I think I'm using the Windows version of [`swprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272937%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), which doesn't require a size as the second parameter.

Comment: I'm not receiving a compiler error, so that indicates I'm using Microsoft's `swprintf`. Also `windows.h` is automatically included I think.

Comment: @cdonts: no, it is not. It may be assumed by your compiler, but it is not automatically included. Didn't you get a warning about using a function without proper prototype (or similar)?

Comment: It may be assumed by the compiler. No, I'm not getting any warning.

Comment: FWIW, you must be using a rather old version of VC++. The [current declaration on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) has a size parameter.

Comment: But that's the VC++ version of `swprintf`, right? I'm using MinGW (the one which comes with C::B).

Comment: MinGW's `stdio.h` has the following comment: `/* These differ from the ISO C prototypes, which have a maxlen parameter (like snprintf).  */`. Seems that they omit it because they use the `msvcrt.dll` functions as much as possible. I'm perplexed. Tsk, tsk, tsk.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Well, I have just installed Ubuntu :lol: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You're using `%c`, but `%c` is for `char`, even when you use it from `wprintf()`.  Use `%lc`, because the parameter is `whar_t`.

```
swprintf(buffer, L"The character is: %lc.", c);
```

This kind of error should normally be caught by compiler warnings, but it doesn't always happen.  In particular, catching this error is tricky because both `%c` and `%lc` *actually* take `int` arguments, not `char` and `wchar_t` (the difference is how they interpret the `int`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right, it shoud be `%lc` but still not working.

Comment: @cdonts: There's something up with your `swprintf()`, since it doesn't take a size parameter.  If you're using MinGW as you say, something really fishy is going on.

Comment: But the docs say there's no `size` parameter (at least  [this docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272937%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)).

Comment: @cdonts: Those docs are 16 years old, old enough to drive a car in the US.

Comment: @cdonts: Here are current docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx

Comment: I see... I'm using the MinGW version that comes with CodeBlocks.

Comment: @cdonts: Your compiler don't complain about passing a size argument as a pointer. Maybe your linker links to another function than the compiler thinks, that is, you include `<wchar.h>`, giving the compiler a prototype of a function the linker won't link to. Yes, definitely fishy.

Comment: @cdonts: I'm afraid I don't know enough about MinGW to diagnose this.  There is a free version of Visual Studio, or you could use GCC or Clang in a VM.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Using Visual C++ Toolkit 2003 I get the same result. I'll see what I try. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To output Unicode (or to be more precise UTF-16LE) to the Windows console, you have to change the file translation mode to `_O_U16TEXT` or `_O_WTEXT`. The latter one includes the `BOM` which isn't of interest in this case.

The file translation mode can be changed with [_setmode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx). But it takes a file descriptor (abbreviated *fd*) and not a `FILE *`! You can get the corresponding *fd* from a `FILE *` with [_fileno](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx).

Here's an example that should work with MinGW and its variants, and also with various Visual Studio versions.

```
#define _CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int
main(void)
{
    wchar_t buffer[50];
    wchar_t c = L'Ɣ';

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    swprintf(buffer, L"The character is: %c.", c); 
    wprintf(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get [`_O_U16TEXT` undeclared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871540/o-wtext-o-u16text-o-u8text-are-these-modes-possible-in-mingw-compiler-ar).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    wchar_t buffer[50];
    wchar_t c = L'☒';

    if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set locale\n");
        return 1;
    }

    swprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, L"The character is %lc.", c);
    wprintf(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

What I changed:

- I added `wchar.h` include required by the use of `swprintf`
- I added size as the second argument of `swprintf` as required by C
- I changed `%c` conversion specification to `%lc`
- I change locale using `setlocale`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that gives me a Segmentation Fault :|

Comment: @cdonts probably because on Windows `swprintf` for whatever reason does not expect the size as the second argument

Comment: @oauh You're right. Now there's no Segmentation Fault, but still not working (I can't see the character).

Comment: @cdonts It works fine on Linux by adding the `setlocale` call, I could n't test it on MinGW but I suppose `setlocale` call may have to be changed.

Comment: @oauh But, does `setlocale` change something in the `wsprintf` behavior? I think the problem is when copying it to the buffer, not when writing to the stdout.

Comment: @cdonts on Linux and on Cygwin without the call to `setlocale` the character will not be correctly printed. MinGW might be a little different.

Comment: Being downvoted (thanks downvoter!) for this answer is a little bit harsh as the program above works well and the issue sounds related to MinGW.

Comment: @oauh You're right, here's my +1 because of your help. Thanks (if you get the trick please tell me!).

Answer (score 0):

This FAQ explains how to use UniCode / wide characters in MinGW:

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/