# How to read wstring by wcin, and write it in console by wcout?

Tags: c++, unicode

I have such problem. I'm Polish. I use polish letters in console. I've found how to write Unicode literals by wcout [StackOverflowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871540/o-wtext-o-u16text-o-u8text-are-these-modes-possible-in-mingw-compiler-ar). But I still don't know, how to read Unicode literals by wcin, and write them back, to console (When I read 'ĄĘÓŁŚŻŹĆŃ', I have wierd output).

How to read polish letters to wstring by wcin, to be able to correctly write them back by wcout?

When I add:

```
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), 0x00020000);
```

it doesn't read numbers;

Please help, thanks. Mike.

EDIT:
Here's my code (of function):

```
void dodaj()
{
  wcout << L"Dodawanie nowego pracownika:\n";
  wstring imie, nazwisko;
  short dzien, miesiac, rok;
  wstring adnotacjaDoDatyUrodzenia, stanowisko, adnotacjaDoPracownika;

  wcout << L"Podaj imię i nazwisko:\nImie: ";
  getline(wcin, imie);
  wcout << L"Nazwisko: ";
  getline(wcin, nazwisko);

  wcout << L"Podaj datę urodzenia:\n";
  dzien = pobierzShort(L"Dzień: ");
  miesiac = pobierzShort(L"Miesiąc: ");
  rok = pobierzShort(L"Rok: ");

  wcout << L"Podaj adnotację do daty urodzenia: ";
  getline(wcin, adnotacjaDoDatyUrodzenia);

  wcout << L"Podaj stanowisko: ";
  getline(wcin, stanowisko);

  wcout << L"Podaj adnotację do pracownika: ";
  getline(wcin, adnotacjaDoPracownika);

  pracownicy.push_back(Pracownik(imie, nazwisko, dzien, miesiac, rok, adnotacjaDoDatyUrodzenia, stanowisko, adnotacjaDoPracownika));
}
```

And the write to console function:

```
    void wyswietlInfoOPracownikach()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pracownicy.size(); i++)
        {
            wcout << L"Pracownik nr " << i << endl;
            pracownicy[i].wyswietlPodsumowanie();
            wcout << endl;
        }
    }


   void Pracownik::wyswietlPodsumowanie()
    {
        wcout << L"Pracownik:\n";
        daneOsobowe.wyswietlDaneOsobiste();
        wcout << L"Data urodzenia:\n";
        dataUrodzenia.wyswietlDate();
        wcout << L"Adres zamieszkania:\n";
        adresZamieszkania.wyswietlAdres();
        wcout << L"Adres zameldowania:\n";
        adresZameldowania.wyswietlAdres();
        wcout << L"Adres korespondencji:\n";
        adresKorespondencji.wyswietlAdres();
        umowy.wyswietlHistorieDat();
        orzeczenia.wyswietlHistorieDat();
        badania.wyswietlHistorieDat();
        urlopy.wyswietlHistorieDat();
        wcout << L"Stanowisko: " << stanowisko << endl;
        wcout << L"Wynagrodzenie brutto: " << wynagrodzenieBrutto << endl;
        wcout << L"Dodatkowe informacje: " << adnotacja << endl;
    }
```

My main():

```
int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), 0x00020000);
    // _setmode(_fileno(stdin), 0x00020000);

    system("cls");
    menu();
    short wybor;
    wybor = pobierzShort(L"Wybierz opcję menu: ");

    while (wybor != 3)
    {
        bool czyWyjsc = false;

        switch (wybor)
        {
            case 1: wyswietlInfoOPracownikach(); break;
            case 2: dodaj(); break;
            case 3: czyWyjsc = true; break;
            default: wcout << L"Dokonano złego wyboru\n"; break;
        }

        if (czyWyjsc)
            break;

        menu();
        wybor = pobierzShort(L"Wybierz opcję menu: ");
        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is halfly solved. I call

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), 0x00020000);
```

when need to read wstring, and

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_TEXT);
```

when I need to read number.

Comment: What are you doing? Instead of describing the code, please show it instead. Preferably please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you reduce your example to a simple main function, execute your setup, read one string, write it and possibly write some static text? Keep function and variable names in english-alike words. I don't see how all this code is relevant for quickly testing unicode read/write. If you have static text inside the code, make sure that your code file encoding and the compiler are compatible...

Comment: Try changing all `wcout`s, `wcin`s and `wstring`s to `cout`s, `cin`s and `string`s, respectively and you should be fine.