# Where to get _fileno and _O_U16TEXT?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, utf, scandir

I'm trying to print the text "Ääkkösiä ruutuun." to console with c++. I have windows 7 and am using Code::Blocks editor. Searching on the subject I found that maybe these sort of lines would help

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
wstring s{L"Ääkkösiä ruutuun."};
wcout<<s<<endl;
```

But when I try to compile it, I get the error: _fileno was not declared in this scope.

I have all these includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ostream>
```

what am I missing?

Also, one other thing I tried was locale, but then locale::empty wasn't found! Why doesn't my c++ have anything in it?

**EDIT**
Here is a picture of what my program is doing now.

It prints out just the first letter (Ä). What happens to the rest?

[image: Ääkkösiä ruutuun, perkele!]

Ok, it seems that setmode sets it so that only one letter gets printed. (Even trying to print normal texts with multiple commands, just results in a single letter.) Without it the scandinavian letters don't print correctly, thought. They look like this:

[image]

Comment: According to Microsoft, `_fileno` is defined in `<stdio.h>`. According to IBM and others, it's `fileno` without an underscore that is defined.

Comment: I've tried both, neither found. By the way, why does one need the .h in stdio as it is not needed for example in "#include <string>?

Comment: I think you need to look at how your development environment is confgured. It sounds like your include paths are not defined. As for `<stdio>` versus `<stdio.h>`, well, the former is standard and the latter ought to work too.

Comment: you do not need `fileno(stdout)` for this. There's a `STDOUT_FILENO` (which is normally equals 1) located in `unistd.h`.

Comment: @Vovanium Ok, That was found. But how about _O_U16TEXT?

Comment: I just checked, and `_fileno` is declared in `stdio.h` on my Visual Studio 2017 setup.

Comment: Ok, I found that that _O_U16TEXT  is the number 0x00020000, so why not just put that in. Hence my code is:  _setmode(STDOUT_FILENO, 0x00020000); It compiles and runs, but... I get just the signle letter "Ä" printed out. Where does the rest go?

Comment: @ploosu2 C standard headers (such as `stdio.h`) have names ending in `.h`. The C++ standard library headers such as `string` don't have any suffix.

Comment: @ploosu2 I don't know about `_O_U16TEXT`. `fileno` etc is common POSIX stuff, but `_setmode` and its flags seem to be Microsoft specific.

Comment: Halleluja, I got it to work! The magic line is setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".OCP");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_O\_WTEXT, \_O\_U16TEXT, \_O\_U8TEXT - are these modes possible in mingw compiler, are there any workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871540/o-wtext-o-u16text-o-u8text-are-these-modes-possible-in-mingw-compiler-ar)

Answer (score 1):

The answer you found is for Visual Studio, not Code::Blocks.

While the C standard specifies what should in in `<stdio.h>`, it only specifies a minimum. Implementors may add their own functions, and should do so using an `_` (underscore prefix). This is why you should NOT use that prefix. You don't know what you'll break. Microsoft clearly signaled their non-standard extensions using the correct prefix.

The answer is tagged C++, but C++ inherits the contents of `<stdio.h>` from C.

Comment: It certainly broke something, since it only prints out one letter. Thankfully not permanently since commenting out that setmode-call reverts it back the garbled scandis but at least it prints everything. Ok, so now I'm trying to search for a Code::Blocks solution. I just don't know what words to use. One would think this is a solved problem of just printing out unicode stuff.

Comment: @ploosu2: The Unicode people themselves seem to be occupied by adding emojis. I can't entirely blame Microsoft nor Code::Blocks for this.

Comment: @ploosu2: If you're willing to set up Code::Blocks to use the mingw-w64 toolchain, you'll have `_fileno`. Alternatively, you can just define it yourself (check the question marked as duplicate in comments to OP).

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".OCP");
```

works!

A complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

wstring readFile(const char* filename) {
    wifstream wif(filename);
    locale myLoc("");
    //locale utf8_locale(locale(), new gel::stdx::utf8cvt<true>);
    wif.imbue(myLoc);
    basic_stringstream<wchar_t> wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".OCP");
    wstring contents = readFile("test.txt");
    wcout<<L"Does anything get printed out at all???"<<endl;
    //wcout <<contents<<endl;
    wstring s{L"Ääkkösiä ruutuun."};
    wcout<<s<<endl;
    wcout<<L"Näkyykö äkköset?"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The text read from file (utf-8) still doesn't print correctly, though.
It should be

> Hei!
>   Täällä on kaksi riviä.

ä's go awry there.

Output:

[image: output with LC_TYPE_OCP]

Comment: That limits you to the OEM codepage, and if it's like MSVC there's a double translation to the console output codepage, which happens to default to OEM as well. Only Windows 10 supports UTF-8 in this case, and that's beta and not the default configuration. In Windows 7 it will be a legacy codepage, limited to about 250 characters for non-Asian locales. If you can't get your C/C++ library to work with the console's Unicode API, you can call `WriteConsoleW` directly with UTF-16LE text.

Comment: `setlocale()` does a very different thing than what you were doing in the question. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337240/3258851), and also the question I linked as possible duplicate in your question.