# What is this ? in the beginning of the console output after reading a text file encoded with Unicode?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode

I've been tinkering with reading files(text files encoded in Unicode) and for some reason I get a question mark in the beginning of the output.

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"dog.txt",
                              GENERIC_READ,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                              NULL);

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); //Making sure the console will 
                                           //display the  wide characters 
                                           //correctly. See below for link

    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    GetFileSizeEx(hFile,&li); 

    WCHAR* pBuf = new WCHAR[li.QuadPart / sizeof(WCHAR)]; //Allocating space for 
                                                          //the file.

    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    BOOL bFinishRead = FALSE;
    do
    {
        bFinishRead = ReadFile(hFile,pBuf,li.QuadPart,&dwRead,NULL);
    } while(!bFinishRead);

    pBuf[li.QuadPart / sizeof(WCHAR)] = 0; //Making sure the end of the output 
                                           //is null-terminated.

    std::wcout << pBuf << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 1;
}
```

dog.txt

```
One Two Three
```

Console output

```
?One Two Three
```

I already eliminated a lot of gibberish by making sure the end of the output is null-terminated but the ? in the beginning puzzles me.

As for the

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

see [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

**Note:** My code is Windows-oriented and I intend to keep it that way if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Pray nobody adds some 0-words to your files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM).  It's standard practice to insert a BOM at the beginning of a text file in UTF-16 to ensure it can be read correctly on different-endian systems (where the individual bytes encoding a UTF-16 double-byte value are in a different order).  You can strip it by checking whether the first `wchar_t` is codepoint `U+FEFF` i.e. has value `0xfeff`.