# Unicode with MSVC++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I know that C++11 now supports unicode (std::u16string/u32string and the u/U prefix). But how exactly do I output unicode to the terminal using visual studio? I am baffled.

Comment: [`_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx) is probably still the way to do it.. after converting from `u32string`

Comment: "C++11 now supports unicode" That's not supporting Unicode. That's simply supporting the storage of UTF-16 and UTF-32 codepoint sequences. Actual Unicode support requires more than this.

Comment: "How do I output Unicode to the terminal?" Answer: *very carefully*!

Comment: Honestly Cygwin's latest terminal is the best method for UTF8 in a console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

Answer (score 0):

As sais before, the c++11 does not offer unicode, but just new string literals for fixed width char char16_t, char8_t char32_t with u"", U""
->NB, this is already better than the previous wchar (16 bits on Win32 and 32 on Mac)

The unicode is however planned, after the complete rewrite of a previous proposal, this should be a much more complete support of unicode : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3398.html

To use a string created with a string literal just use the << operator. (e.g. for cout)

Note that you can read the support of c++11 features here : [this is not really complete yet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)
i tried the char16_t and char32_t types, they are defined, but I don't think it is the final support more a transitional support.
The string literals are perhaps not yet supported.

Comment: Yeah, MSVC's `char16_t` and `char32_t` were just placeholder typedefs up until VS 2015 was released, so operations involving them weren't really complete.