# C++ unicode box character drawing when overloading I/O operators

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, console, iostream

I just read [Joel's blog post on unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and found the characters the I want to use to draw boxes in the console [in this pdf from the unicode website](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf).

Displaying these characters is simple enough when done directly with `cout`, i.e. the following does what it is supposed to do..

```
    cout << u8"\u256C";
```

However, I am doing some overloading as shown in the following snippets, and I cannot figure out how to get the box characters to display correctly.

I render my data like so ...

```
// This is the main rendering code
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const DataGrid& dg)
{
    for(auto row : dg.data)
    {
        string tmp; //Make empty string
        for(auto col : row)
            tmp.append(   1, dg.gfxString[col]  );
        os << tmp << endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Make it friends with my data model...

```
class DataGrid
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const DataGrid& dg);

    //EDIT: rest of class added on request
    DataGrid(Rectangle _rect = Rectangle(Point(0,0), Point(5,5))) :
    rect(_rect),
    data ( vector<vector<p_t>> (_rect.getHeight(), vector<p_t>(_rect.getWidth(), p_t::EMPTY))  ){}

    void addPoint(Point p, p_t type)
    { 
        data[p.getY()][p.getX()] = type;
    }

    void addBorder()
    {
        //Top and bottom
        fill_n(data[0].begin()+1, rect.getWidth()-2, p_t::BORDER_T);
        fill_n(data[rect.getBtm()].begin()+1, rect.getWidth()-2, p_t::BORDER_B);

        //Left and right hand border edges
        for (int nn=1; nn<rect.getHeight()-1; ++nn){
            addPoint(Point(rect.getLeft(), nn), p_t::BORDER_L);
            addPoint(Point(rect.getRight(), nn), p_t::BORDER_R);
        }

        //Corners
        addPoint(rect.getTL(), p_t::BORDER_TL);
        addPoint(rect.getTR(), p_t::BORDER_TR);
        addPoint(rect.getBL(), p_t::BORDER_BL);
        addPoint(rect.getBR(), p_t::BORDER_BR);
    }


private:
    Rectangle rect;
     vector<vector<p_t>> data; //p_t is an enum

    //string gfxString = " abcdefghijklmnop"; //This works fine
    string gfxString = u8"\u256C\u256C\u256C\u256C\u256C\u256C\u256C\u256C"; //Nope     
};
```

Then attempt to render it with the following, but get gibberish ...

```
DataGrid p = DataGrid(Rectangle(Point(0,0), 40, 10));
p.addBorder();
cout << p;
```

If anyone can spot a fix, then that would be great. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Instead of "BLAH", please present an actual testcase so we can see what you're doing and therefore what you're doing wrong.

Comment: First stop: [stop using `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)! It definitely never ever has any place in an output operator! Won't fix you problem but improve your code still.

Comment: Added as requested ( ugly as it is ;] )

Comment: It is going through a transform on the way. The chars in the string are being selected depending on the contents of `dg.data`. THis is just a very early play anyway ;)

Comment: Despite using wstrings, use `\x` instead of `\u` for numeric escapes and `SetConsoleOutputCP()` if you run this on windows (if so, also take a look at `WideCharToMultiByte()`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/1175253

Comment: @Sam Eeek. Now platform dependencies in the mix. I swear these box characters were so easy to draw in C project I did a looooong time back. Pretty sure I just pasted them into a char array and they drew just fine.

Comment: xD. Well, at least I did finally end up with that Windows API stuff while porting a linux project to windows.

Comment: @Sam .The old favorites ... `+-|` are looking like an increasingly attractive solution to draw boxes! I'm only doing it for (1980s style) eye candy, not foreign char sets!

Comment: No offense meant. Its just that all that CP850 stuff and so on caused me some headache, thus using wide chars. Plain C++ brought me portability until the linker finished its job. What I haven't done so far is looking into the windows port of ncurses to draw these boxes without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I assume that string is std::string, not a wide string. Each of those box characters occupies three bytes, so you can't just say gfxString[col], even if col were the correct offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change gfxString to a vector of std::strings (or even a std::array):

```
// Probably in the final code, these are not all the same value
std::array<std::string, 8> gfxString = {
   { u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   , u8"\u256C"
   }};
```

Or even just an array of `const char*`.

Comment: Nice, +1. Why array over vector?

Comment: @learnvst, doesn't make much difference. But it's a known-length constant so it falls into the use case for std::array.