# Why command doesn't executes if contains Russian letters?

Tags: c#

I tried to disconnect/connect my modem adapter, named as "конект", but it doesn't work, because adapter's name contains Russian letters. How to force it to work? Please help.

> Connect("конект", "", "", true);

```
    public static void Connect(string adapter, string login, string pass, bool discon)
    {
        string cmd = "";
        if (discon)
        {
            cmd = "rasdial " + '"' + adapter + '"' + @" /disconnect";
        }
        else
        {
            cmd = "rasdial " + '"' + adapter + '"' + " " + login + " " + pass;
        }
        Cmd(cmd);
    }
    public static void Cmd(string URL)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe");
        Process p = new Process();
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p = Process.Start(startInfo);
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(URL);
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"EXIT");
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
    }
```

[I know that need just rename adapter with English letters and code will work, but I want to know how to force it work with Russian letters]

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an exception, or does it just mean it will not disconnect?

Comment: what happens when you try with the russian letters?

Comment: No exceptions. Nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried to use: Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(adapter))

Comment: Is 'adapter' the host name? Can you look it up using .NET and pass its IP address instead? To see output, I guess you'd have to read stderr and stdout.

Comment: It has to be an encoding issue, but where along the line is the encoding switching from Unicode to ASCII?  It looks like you're just running a shell with your assembled string.  Does this work from the command line, or is the problem outside the C# code?

Comment: It works when I enter command manually in cmd.exe, but doesn't when via C#.
I tried without hiding cmd.exe's window, but nothing seen there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/327083

Comment: Question solved, thanks to Hans Passant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine(URL);
```

ProcessStartInfo is missing a StandardInputEncoding property.  That makes it likely that a "URL" string that contains Cyrillic characters is going to get mangled if this code runs on machine that doesn't have a cyrillic code page as the default system code page.

You really want to avoid using input redirection here, it just isn't necessary.  Use the /c command option for cmd.exe so that you can pass the command line directly:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c " + URL;
p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Fwiw, not necessary to use cmd.exe either, just run rasdial.exe directly.

Comment: The last line is probably the most important.