# getting a sub string of a std::wstring

Tags: c++, substring, non-ascii-characters, wstring

How can I get a substring of a `std::wstring` which includes some non-ASCII characters?

The following code does not output anything:
(The text is an Arabic word contains 4 characters where each character has two bytes, plus the word "Hello")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wstring s = L"سلام hello";
    wcout << s.substr(0,3) << endl;
    wcout << s.substr(4,5) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second should at least print " hell", and does on Coliru. The first might not be printable on the console you're supposedly using.

Comment: yeah, that's the strange part. I'm getting nothing.

Comment: What OS are you running this code on?

Comment: AFAIK the console has limited support for Unicode (due to a mix of CRT weirdness and limits of the selection of fonts available for the console), but YMMV.

Comment: In particular, first setup the whole thing correctly to print Unicode on the console (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx, and http://blog.wolffmyren.com/2009/02/26/necessary-criteria-for-fonts-to-be-available-in-a-command-window/ if the default font does not have the glyphs you need), *then* do your experiments with substrings and whatever.

Comment: This question is not about UTF-8.

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Your question is worded as though the problem is getting the substring, and all the comments are saying it might just be writing to console that's the issue. By putting the substrings into local wstrings, you should be able to establish which is the issue and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: if anyone is finding split a wstring, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812132/splitting-stdwstring-into-stdvector

Answer (score 2):

This should work: **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1a98e0a9bbda086ddaf980a637c1a9ab-93e6c6235a92d0c233f44beab03470ad)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp>

using namespace std;

template <typename C>
std::string to_utf8(C const& in)
{
    std::string result;
    auto out = std::back_inserter(result);
    auto utf8out = boost::utf8_output_iterator<decltype(out)>(out);

    std::copy(begin(in), end(in), utf8out);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    wstring s = L"سلام hello";

    auto first  = s.substr(0,3);
    auto second = s.substr(4,5);

    cout << to_utf8(first)  << endl;
    cout << to_utf8(second) << endl;
}
```

Prints

```
سلا
 hell
```

**Frankly** though, I think your `substring` calls are making weird assumptions. <strike>Let me suggest a fix for that in a minute:</strike>

Comment: Is your definition of "a minute" 7 years? 

Comment: @CodeDoggo apparently I do forget things once in a while :)