# c++ can't get "wcout" to print unicode, and leave "cout" working

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, cout

can't get "wcout" to print unicode string in multiple code pages, together with leaving "cout" to work

please help me get these 3 lines to work together.

```
std::wcout<<"abc "<<L'\u240d'<<" defg "<<L'א'<<" hijk"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"hello world from cout! \n";
std::wcout<<"hello world from wcout! \n";
```

output:

```
abc hello world from cout!
```

i tried:

```
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
```

problem:
"wcout" failed

tried:

```
std::locale mylocale("");
std::wcout.imbue(mylocale);
```

and:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

and

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

and

```
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)
```

Nothing worked

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't see how this is limited to Windows. It's fact of the C++ and C standards.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You are right, sry. Did shoot too fast, due to some windows only functions used. Also, they have extra trouble for unicode.

Comment: Related at least for windows: https://web.archive.org/web/20111005003105/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/10/07/10072032.aspx

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
Not a complete solution but at least not freezing cout\wcout cursor after printing Unicode: 
std::locale mylocale(""); 
std::wcout.imbue(mylocale);

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft requires a bit of non-standard set-up with `_setmode()` before `wcout` or `wcin` can work.  This example is pretty heavy on the boilerplate, so not as clear as it could possibly be, but it runs on clang++, g++ and MSVC++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MS_STDLIB_BUGS // Allow overriding the autodetection.
/* The Microsoft C and C++ runtime libraries that ship with Visual Studio, as
 * of 2017, have a bug that neither stdio, iostreams or wide iostreams can
 * handle Unicode input or output.  Windows needs some non-standard magic to
 * work around that.  This includes programs compiled with MinGW and Clang
 * for the win32 and win64 targets.
 */
#  if ( _MSC_VER || __MINGW32__ || __MSVCRT__ )
    /* This code is being compiled either on MS Visual C++, or MinGW, or
     * clang++ in compatibility mode for either, or is being linked to the
     * msvcrt.dll runtime.
     */
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 1
#  else
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 0
#  endif
#endif

#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
#  include <io.h>
#  include <fcntl.h>
#endif

#if !HAS_APP17_FILESYSTEM && !HAS_TS_FILESYSTEM && __has_include(<filesystem>)
#  include <filesystem> /* MSVC has this header, but not the standard API. */
#  if __cpp_lib_filesystem >= 201703
#    define HAS_CPP17_FILESYSTEM 1
#  endif
#endif

#if !HAS_CPP17_FILESYSTEM && __has_include(<experimental/filesystem>)
#  include <experimental/filesystem>
/* Microsoft screws this one up, too, by not defining the feature-test
 * macro specified by the standard.
 */
#  if __cpp_lib_experimental_filesystem >= 201406 || MS_STDLIB_BUGS
#    define HAS_TS_FILESYSTEM 1
/* With g++6, this requires -lstdc++fs, AFTER this source file on the
 * command line.
 */
#  endif
#endif

#if HAS_CPP17_FILESYSTEM
  using std::filesystem::absolute;
  using std::filesystem::current_path;
  using std::filesystem::directory_entry;
  using std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
  using std::filesystem::is_directory;
  using std::filesystem::exists;
  using std::filesystem::path;
#elif HAS_TS_FILESYSTEM
  using std::experimental::filesystem::absolute;
  using std::experimental::filesystem::current_path;
  using std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry;
  using std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator;
  using std::experimental::filesystem::is_directory;
  using std::experimental::filesystem::exists;
  using std::experimental::filesystem::path;
#else
#  error "This library has neither <filesystem> nor <experimental/filesystem>."
#endif

void init_locale(void)
// Does magic so that wcout can work.
{
#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
  // Windows needs a little non-standard magic.
  constexpr char cp_utf16le[] = ".1200"; // UTF-16 little-endian locale.
  setlocale( LC_ALL, cp_utf16le );
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT );
  /* Repeat for _fileno(stdin), if needed. */
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  constexpr char locale_name[] = "";
  setlocale( LC_ALL, locale_name );
  std::locale::global(std::locale(locale_name));
  std::wcin.imbue(std::locale())
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
#endif
}

using std::endl;

int main( const int argc, const char * const argv[] )
{
  init_locale();

  const path cwd = (argc > 1) ? absolute(path( argv[1], std::locale() ))
                              : absolute(current_path());

  if (exists(cwd)) {
    std::wcout << cwd.wstring() << endl;
  } else {
    std::wcerr << "Path does not exist.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (is_directory(cwd)) {
    for ( const directory_entry &f : directory_iterator(cwd) )
      std::wcout << f.path().filename().wstring() << endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That’s probably a lot more complicated than it really needed to be: `std::filesystem` is unsupported as of 2018, but `<experimental/filesystem>` is never going to be removed.

Here’s a simplified version that includes only the boilerplate to get `wcout` to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <locale.h>

#ifndef MS_STDLIB_BUGS
#  if ( _MSC_VER || __MINGW32__ || __MSVCRT__ )
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 1
#  else
#    define MS_STDLIB_BUGS 0
#  endif
#endif

#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
#  include <io.h>
#  include <fcntl.h>
#endif

void init_locale(void)
{
#if MS_STDLIB_BUGS
  constexpr char cp_utf16le[] = ".1200";
  setlocale( LC_ALL, cp_utf16le );
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT );
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  constexpr char locale_name[] = "";
  setlocale( LC_ALL, locale_name );
  std::locale::global(std::locale(locale_name));
  std::wcin.imbue(std::locale())
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 10):

C++ says:

> `[C++11: 27.4.1/3]:` Mixing operations on corresponding wide- and narrow-character streams follows the same semantics as mixing such operations on `FILE`s, as specified in Amendment 1 of the ISO C standard.

And [the referenced document](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/login_mse.html) says:

> The definition of a stream was changed to include the concept of an orientation for both text and binary streams. After a stream is associated with a file, but before any operations are performed on the stream, the stream is without orientation. If a wide-character input or output function is applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes wide-oriented. Likewise, if a byte input or output operation is applied to a stream with orientation, the stream becomes byte-oriented. Thereafter, only the `fwide()` or `freopen()` functions can alter the orientation of a stream.
>
> **Byte input/output functions shall not be applied to a wide-oriented stream and wide-character input/output functions shall not be applied to a byte-oriented stream.**

By my interpretation this means, in short, **do not mix `std::cout` and `std::wcout`**.

Answer (score 2):

It's because Unicode is not representable in the codepage causing **wcout** to fail.

```
std::wcout<<"abc "<<L'\u240d'<<" defg "<<L'א'<<" hijk"<<std::endl;
if(std::wcout.fail()){
    std::cout<<"\nConversion didn't succeed\n";
    std::wcout << "This statement has no effect on the console";
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::wcout<<"hello world from wcout! \n";
}
std::cout<<"hello world from cout! \n";
std::wcout<<"hello world from wcout again! \n";
```