# glfwGetMonitorName returns obfuscated string c++

Tags: c++, encoding, glfw

I want to dump my monitors(I have only one though), and I used this code:

```cpp
GLFWmonitor** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&num);
cout << "Monitors dump:" << endl;
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
    const char* name = glfwGetMonitorName(monitors[i]);
    cout << (string)name << endl;
}
```

The returned string is all obfuscated:

#### `閫氱敤鍗虫彃鍗崇敤鐩戣鍣`

I have a Chinese system, but in my system monitor screen, the name is `HP N246v` which is DEFINITELY utf-8(no Chinese characters), so I'm thinking, maybe it is utf-8, but encoded in utf-16. Nevertheless, I want `glfwGetMonitorName` to return properly encoded strings. Also, I seriously want a way to get GLFW to return utf-16 characters. But it's okay(since utf-16 isn't supported well over libraries and codes due to most English text is in utf-8.)

Comment: Are you compiling with Unicode support, I doubt if the monitor name is returned in Chinese instead of English! There are times when we process ANSI instead of Unicode you get buffer overflow and resulting in non-English or non-printable characters

Comment: Before printing anything to stdout, call this `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`, because the console output may not print the UTF-8 strings properly.

Comment: `(string)name` tells the compiler to interpret `name` as if it was a `std::string` instance. Just `cout << name` should suffice.

Comment: std::cout does not handle UTF-8.  Have you tried to convert the monitor name from UTF-8 to UTF-16 and print using std::wcout  ?  This would at least give you a better idea of what the actual returned name is.

Comment: @Michaël Roy std::wcout prints NOTHING to the console.

Comment: @Anand Sowmithiran That requires #include<windows.h> which I suppose is Windows-only and will hurt portability since I am going to send the program to a Mac friend.

Comment: @Botje that didn't help and it prints the same things.

Comment: @Michaël Roy I tried using the boilerplate from the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950412/c-cant-get-wcout-to-print-unicode-and-leave-cout-working), still no luck.

Comment: Can you inspect the actual bytes returned by `glfwGetMonitorName` with a debugger instead of printing them to the terminal? Also, statements like "utf-8, but encoded in utf-16" make me think you don't fully grasp the concept and terminology of unicode.

Comment: @Botje i mean all characters are perfectly within the UTF-8 range(that is, encodeable with UTF-8 after decoded from UTF-16) BUT the bytes returned are UTF-16 code.

Comment: Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 can represent the full Unicode range. Your statement does not make any sense to me, sorry. That is why I asked to see the actual bytes.

Comment: I know there is a "supplementry range" for UTF-8 but i dont think most functions support that