# Unicode output on windows console

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, g++, console-application

The article Unicode apps in the MinGW-w64 wiki explains the following example for an Unicode application, e.g. `_main.c_`:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR * argv[])
{
  _tprintf(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

> The above code makes use of tchar.h mapping, which allows it to both compile in Unicode and non-Unicode mode. [...] The `-municode` option is still required when linking if Unicode mode is used.

So I used

```
C:\> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -municode -o hello
_tmain.c:1:0: warning: "UNICODE" redefined
#define UNICODE
^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

to compile a Unicode application. But, when I run it, it returns

```
C:\> hello Süßer
S³▀er
```

So the Unicode string is wrong. I used the latest version 4.9.2 of MinGW-w64, i686 architecture and tried the Win32 and POSIX theads variants, both result in the same error. My operating system is 32-bit German Windows 7. When I used the Unicode codepage (`chcp 65001`), I have to use the font "Lucida Console". With this setting I get a similar error:

```
C:\> hello Süßer
S��er
```

I want to use a parameter with "ü" or "ß" in a Windows C++ program.

## Solution

nwellnhof is right: The problem is the output on the console. This problem is explained in [Unicode part 1: Windows console i/o approaches](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/) und [Unicode part 2: UTF-8 stream mode](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/). The latter gives a solution for  Visual C++ - it worked also with Intel C++ 15. This blog post does "not yet consider the g++ compiler. All this code is Visual C++ specific. However, [the blog author has] done generally the same with g++, and [he] will probably discuss that in a third installment."

I want to open a file, which name is given by a parameter. This works simple, e. g. *main.c*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if ( argc > 1 ) {
        // The output will be wrong, ...
        cout << argv[1] << endl;

        // but the name of this file will be right:
        fstream fl_rsl(argv[1], ios::out);
        fl_rsl.close();
    }
   return 0;
}
```

and the compilation without unicode mode

```
C:\> g++ main.cpp -o hello && hello Süßer
```

It's console output is still wrong, but the created filename is right. This is okay for me.

Comment: Your program is correct, but your terminal uses the wrong code page (probably code page 850).

Comment: @nwellnhof: I tried it with unicode codepage - see edit. But, I get a similar error.

Comment: It's still a console issue. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app).

Comment: You could check out [`WriteConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx) - it says it's able to handle either Unicode or ANSI characters, but confusingly does not tell you how to choose which one.

Comment: Another promising approach: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b941b3c4-7c00-4f77-9d2f-acb9e9085449/writeconsole-wcout-wprintf-and-unicode

Comment: @MarkRansom: This approach is the same like in the two blog posts unter "Solution" - this does not work with g++.

Comment: I just went through the links you provided - ouch! Things are really a mess in Windows Console land. I wish Microsoft would find a way to make UTF-8 a first class citizen, the way Linux does.