# GetComputerName() not displaying Unicode correctly in Windows console

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm relatively new to WinAPI programming in C++. I'm trying to write a program that will obtain the system hostname using GetComputerName(). Ideally, I want the code to be able to work on English and non-English systems. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
int main()
{
    wstring hostname;
    wchar_t nbtName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD length = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
    GetComputerName(nbtName, &length);
    hostname = nbtName;

    wcout << hostname << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine on my English Windows 7 system, but the code doesn't seem to display properly on my German Windows 7 system (which uses German characters for the hostname). I thought that wstring and wchar_t could handle these special characters. Here's what's displayed on my German Windows 7 system.

```
COMPUTER-Í─▄▀
```

Am I overlooking something stupid? Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy/paste the name into the console successfully? Perhaps the console is using a font which has different glyphs for the required code-points.

Comment: If I use the Windows "hostname" command, the German characters show up correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` to show Unicode in console window:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h> //for _setmode
#include <fcntl.h> //for _O_U16TEXT

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"ελληνικά\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Or use `MessageBoxW(0, hostname.c_str(), 0, 0)` or `OutputDebugStringW` to see Unicode text displayed correctly:

Answer (score 1):

this function has two versions `GetComputerNameW` for unicode and `GetComputerNameA` for ANSI. if UNICODE is defined in your environment the the first one will be called. So either make sure UNICODE is defined or try to call the `GetComputerNameW` directly.

Comment: Unicode is defined in my project. I tried the GetComputerNameW() function instead of the GetComputerName() but the issue is still the same.

Comment: @t3ntman Then maybe your problem is your console output not displaying Unicode characters properly. there is a discussion about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216113/unicode-output-on-windows-console?rq=1)

Comment: I'll investigate it, but I find it strange that the native Windows executable like "hostname" would display the correct hostname, but my program does not.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Console output was the culprit. The Unicode characters display correctly in other non-console output. Thanks everyone!