# How to print this word "☻" in the console window?(c/c++)

Tags: c++

```
wcout.imbue(std::locale("chs"));
wchar_t *a = L"☻";
wcout << *a;
```

It's not work, why? What should I do?

Comment: Use an unicode font in your console, e.g. "Lucida console fonts"

Comment: What does 'not work' mean? Nothing happens? It prints something else?

Comment: What is happening when you do this?

Comment: What compiler and what platform (confirm it supports Chinese) are you using?

Comment: see this post for printing Unicode in Windows' console http://stackoverflow.com/a/36527398/4603670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible errors:

- Your compiler is possibly not recognising the `L"☻"` as a unicode string in the source file.
- Your console doesn't support it

You could use the unicode character code for it instead (`"\u263B"`). Make sure the console supports unicode and that the font has a corresponding character for it.

It may also be easier (depending on the compiler support) to use the [unicode character literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for C++ 11;

```
char a[] = u8"My \u263B character";
cout << a;
```

Comment: //char * str = "\x263B"; 
 //wcout << str;
 //wcout << "\x263B";
 //printf("%c","\x263B");
 //puts("\x263B");
C2022: error "9787": too large for character

Comment: I'm not sure how much standard unicode support is in the "wide" implementations in Windows. But as you post the code, you should use `wchar_t` and `wprintf` etc. for the wide versions of the C++ runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Its the Unicode 263B [source](http://unicode-table.com/de/search/?q=%E2%98%BB)

Simple use the `wchar_t a = 0x263B`;

Comment: Undefined identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (`u8` since `c++11`):

```
char smiley[] { u8"\u263b" };
cout << smiley << '\n';
```

Or you could also just do:

```
char smiley[] { "\u263b" };
cout << smiley << '\n';
```