# Printing Unicode Japanese characters with WriteConsoleW

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi

So, I'm trying to print some Japanese characters. I tried every possible thing. What am I missing?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void printW(const T* text) {
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), text, std::char_traits<T>::length(text), 0, 0);
}

template<typename T>
void print(const T* text) {
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), text, std::char_traits<T>::length(text), 0, 0);
}

int main() 
{
    //const char* text = "こんにちは\n";
    const wchar_t* textL = L"こんにちは\n";
    const char16_t* textu = u"こんにちは\n";
    const char32_t* textU = U"こんにちは\n";

    //printW(text);
    printW(textL);
    printW(textu);
    printW(textU);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested to make sure your console even supports Japanese characters?

Comment: I don't think any of those answers work in Windows. See this link instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36527398/4603670

Answer (score -5):

WinAPI not needed, also you're using the wrong types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string text{u8"こんにちは"};
    std::cout << text;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/064c2034ebf95ff4)

If you need to use the WinAPI, minimal modification is needed:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void print(const T* text) {
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), text, std::char_traits<T>::length(text), 0, 0);
}

int main() 
{
    auto text = u8"こんにちは\n";
    print(text);
}
```

<sup>disclaimer: not tested on actual windows machine</sup>

Comment: Windows doesn't support UTF8

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Windows does support UTF-8 (the entire .NET metadata is encoded using UTF-8, for example). The implementation for console codepage 65001 (UTF-8) has limitations.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't know what .NET does. I mean WinAPI does not support UTF-8 screen output, or UTF-8 keyboard input. You can manipulate UTF-8 or any other data and use UTF-16 conversion. Maybe some .NET stuff can work directly with UTF-8

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It's a far stretch to say that *"Windows doesn't support UTF8"*. It does, just not everywhere. Windows' native Unicode encoding is UTF-16LE, and whenever you access system services, that's the character encoding you need to use. However, functions like [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) have full support for UTF-8 (and that's what Microsoft's CLR implementation uses to en-/decode .NET metadata).

Comment: I would like either you to explain what `u8` does on MSVC, a C++11 compliant compiler. Explain to me how `u8` is remotely the same concept as `wchar_t` because it isn't.

Comment: MSVC 14 has full support for explicit UTF-8 encoded string literals, and the contents of your *text* variable holds a string encoded using UTF-8. Your suggested solution breaks, because you are then passing that variable to an API call that expects ANSI (codepage) encoding. Obviously, a string literal prefix and a data type are different concepts. Not sure, what point you were trying to express here.