# c++ can't get local user groups by NetUserGetGroups()

Tags: c++, winapi

Can't figure out how to work with all these "wide unicode strings". Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? I Just want to get all local user groups, so i do:

```
LPBYTE buffer;
DWORD entries, total_entries;
NetUserGetLocalGroups(NULL, L"rovnyart", 0, LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT, &buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_SIZE, &entries, &total_entries);
LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *groups = (LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *) buffer;

unsigned int i;
for (i=0; i<entries;i++)
    wprintf(L"%s\n", groups[i].lgrui0_name);
```

And this is what i get:

```
t
╝4╝<╝8╝=╝8╝A╝B╝@╝0╝B╝>╝@╝K╝
╝>╝;╝L╝7╝>╝2╝0╝B╝5╝;╝8╝

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My windows language is Russian, but i created one group called "testgroup1", and as you can see it doesn't display correct too.

i tried `wprintf()` - result was the same :(

What am i doing wrong?

UPD:

Ok, I changed the code to fit your advices. I created a group called "test" which is non-cyrillic and put my user there.

[image: sorry for non-english text]

Here's my code:

```
LPBYTE pBuf = NULL;

NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
DWORD entries, total_entries;
nStatus = NetUserGetLocalGroups(NULL, L"rovnyart", 0, LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT,  &pBuf, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &entries, &total_entries);

LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *groups = (LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *) pBuf;
if (nStatus == 0) {
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < entries; i++)
        wprintf(L"%s\n", groups[i].lgrui0_name);


    NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
t
╝4╝<╝8╝=╝8╝A╝B╝@╝0╝B╝>╝@╝K╝
╝>╝;╝L╝7╝>╝2╝0╝B╝5╝;╝8╝

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: There's fully working sample code in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370655.aspx).

Comment: I'd note that your code isn't checking for success, isn't zeroing the outputs, and is passing `-1` as `prefmaxlen`. (The documentation's sample uses `MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH `)

Comment: Astounding that people attempt to code against an API without reading the documentation first. Does that ever work out well for anybody?

Comment: i read documentation. sample from there doesn't work on my system too. i am not stupid to ask questions without reading docs first.

Comment: At least one thing you are doing wrong is passing a wide char array to '%s' (which wants a narrow char pointer).  You'll either need to use `%S`, or `wprintf`.  What happens when you fix all the errors that have been identified so far?

Comment: The sample code uses `wprintf`, where your's goes with `printf`. You don't even have to understand the sample, to get it right. The issue here really is, that you didn't understand the sample code, and tried to change it. That's not going to work, ever. Please read [Unicode in the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089.aspx). All of it.

Comment: ok, i changed code to use wprintf. result is the same - these awful symbols instead of group names.

Comment: And still, disregard for the documentation. Where did you check the return value of the function call? Perhaps it failed. How would you know?

Comment: No, function returns zero. the value of `entries` is correct. The problem is that group names are cyrillic, i tried to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")` - nothing helpes.

Comment: You really need to read [Unicode in the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089.aspx). It's not like cyrillic is somehow different from latin characters. Both are in the BMP. It seems you should also read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: It is very likely that the console window is the problem here. Its Unicode support is lacking out of the box. Use the debugger, insert a breakpoint on the `wprintf` line. What does the buffer contain?

Comment: Better now that you added error checking. If this is C++ you need to stop using printf and use iostreams. Then the compiler can help you and make sure the text encoding is interpretation  correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, including guys who downvoted me. The solution of my problem was in `%s` format specifier. I needed to use `%S`.My program correctly outputs group names with:

```
wprintf(L"%S\n", groups[i].lgruiu0_name);
```

Although this code is error-higlighted in my CLion, it works  for some reason.

Thanks for all helpful links.

Comment: This is highly improbable. [LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370282.aspx) stores a wide character string. The `%S` specifier instructs `wprintf` to interpret its string parameter as an MBCS (narrow) string. Is this a bug in your build environment? What results do you get using Visual Studio instead?

Comment: Change it back to `wprintfs(L"%s\n",...)`. Use `_setmode` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36527398/4603670) for printing Unicode on console. Probably `groups[i].lgruiu0_name` looks okay if you test it with `MessageBoxW`

Comment: I recommend avoiding the whole mess by using MessageBoxW() for your diagnostic output rather than outputting to the console.