# Bird Unicode c++ win32

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win32gui

So my teacher made me a challenge of putting a bird into a c++ win32 program. I found a unicode U+1F426  but how can I put it? Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as you're using an [output medium that supports printing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/332733) you can easily via UTF-16 strings: `L"\U0001f426"` although `L""` [may work as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Console output is unlikely to work, I'd suggest displaying to a window instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom I linked to a question that shows how to display unicode correctly on the console. But you are correct in the sense that you'll need to use a font that will support that character. Sadly my Win32 UI skills are lacking.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the `_setmode` call the first time I saw this answer, that changes everything. You're still unlikely to have the character in your console font, but at least it's not completely unfeasible.

Comment: On systems where `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in size, you might need to use `L"\uD83D\uDC26"` instead of `L"\U0001f426"`, depending on your compiler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau aye, but this is windows and it supports the use of the character directly according to MSDN

Comment: @Mgetz: Again, it depends on whether the compiler you are using supports the `\U` (uppercase U) syntax for defining a UTF-32 codepoint value in a UTF-16 wide literal. Otherwise, use the `\u` (lowercase u) syntax to define the individual UTF-16 codeunits for the codepoint.