# c++ literal u8 and BOM (Byte Order Mask)

Tags: c++, unicode, string-literals, codepages

I decided to write a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << u8"это строка6" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Executed in the console the following command:
chcp 65001

Programm output:

```
��то строка6
```

Why is the first character is not displayed correctly? I think that the codepage 65001 uses BOM, and read first symbol as BOM. Is this true?

Comment: The title mentions a BOM, the question doesn't. Where is the hidden link?

Comment: Does your console support unicode characters?

Comment: Yes, my console support unicode characters. Also only a firt symbol displays incorrectly.

Comment: can you `std::wcout`?

Comment: What do you mean by "65001 uses BOM"?

Comment: I mean that each string that could be decoded by codepage 65001 must contains BOM as first symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Well the entire standard IO library is dodgy with that code page. Here's another test program (`\xe2\x86\x92` is the arrow `→` in UTF-8):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "\xe2\x86\x92 a \xe2\x86\x92 b\n";
    int l = (int) sizeof(s) - 1;
    int wr = fwrite(s, 1, l, stdout);
    printf("%d/%d written\n", wr, l);
    return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
��� a → b
10/12 written
```

Note that the first character is again replaced by the `���` (it's 3 bytes in UTF-8), and the `fwrite` call returns the number of **characters** written on the console. This is a violation of the C standard (it should return the number of *bytes*), and it will break every program using fwrite or related functions correctly (for instance, try to print `"☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺"` with Python 3.4).

So your only options to reliably output Unicode text are Windows-specific (unless these issues are fixed in the latest version of MSVC):

- Use wide output functions, as described here: [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)
- Use `WriteConsoleW` (the wide version). Make sure you test if the standard output or error handle is actually a console.