# Visual C++ debug output displaying ???? for non Latin (Cyrillic) characters

Tags: visual-studio-2012, codepages

There is some Windows/VS setting that will let debug output in VS correctly output non Latin characters. We are interested in Cyrillic letters. What is that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Too brief question. However, a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/3439404) could help:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout 
        << L"Unicode test -- Ελληνικά -- čeština -- русский язык -- Türkçesi" 
        << std::endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        std::wcout << L"param " << i << L": " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Verified using Visual Studio 2013:

```
==> ".\so36212399\Debug\so36212399.exe" qwertz ςερτυθ ěščřžý йцукен ğüşıöç
Unicode test -- Ελληνικά -- čeština -- русский язык -- Türkçesi
param 1: qwertz
param 2: ςερτυθ
param 3: ěščřžý
param 4: йцукен
param 5: ğüşıöç

==>
```