# Unicode doesn't output correctly (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, unicode, windows-10, codeblocks

I am a beginner programmer and I'm working on a simple game. I want to output Unicode symbols like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> █ to the console. I am using CodeBlocks on Windows 10 and I am using GNU GCC compiler.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\u2588";
    return 0;
}
```

What I get on console is a few strange symbols. This happens even with other Unicode characters, but the symbols are different.

I tried using `wcout`, but then i get just a blank space instead.

I also tried things like this:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

But then I get errors that `_fileno` and `_O_U16TEXT` was not declared, though I imported the libraries that seem to be necessary for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
```

The Unicode symbols are not totally necessary for my game, but I just want it look nicer.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Command Prompt uses CP850 as encoding by default, and won't be able to correctly display this symbol or any Unicode symbol for that matter [unless you change it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/156811).

It has, however, its own version of it, `\xDB` that is probably what you are looking for.

For other symbols you can use in the Windows Command Prompt, open `charmap.exe` and check the font `Terminal`, there's a range of useful symbols that should be compatible with CP850 and display under the Command Prompt the same way they are presented there.

Comment: The Windows Command Prompt uses an ANSI encoding by default, which varies by Windows localization.  CP850 is a Western European default.  It is CP437 in the US.  The `chcp` command will show the current code page.

Comment: And another thing: how to know the char code that i have to use? The charmap still shows the code of Full Block █ as U+2588, though i need '\xDB' for that to work

Comment: @UrbanRock If the font is Terminal it should show 0xDB for that symbol, at least it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to print `wchar_t` (16 bits long) characters with `std::cout` that only supports `char` (8 bits long). Use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`, `wcout` is meant for wide characters.

Comment: I tried this with wcout, but nothing gets outputted, unless i go to \u256 or lower. When i try \u257 or higher it outputs either nothing or multiple symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have addressed treating the string as a UTF-16 literal. You can also tell the compiler to treat it as a utf-8 literal (forcing it to encode all characters within it as utf-8) by prefixing it with `u8`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << u8"\u2588";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that windows consoles aren't by default set to treat output as utf-8, so this still won't display correctly without some additional settings.