# Why is my unicode string not being handled (printed/copied) correctly?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, escaping

I'm trying to make a program that can work with unicode strings, eventually being able to copy them to the Windows clipboard.

I began with a simple `cout` test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it wasn't handling the unicode, and instead, returned:

```
( ═í┬░ ═£╩û ═í┬░)
```

I had a feeling the issue was that the code file wasn't even being saved with the unicode characters, so I decided to represent them with escape sequences from [here](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/unicode_escape_sequence_converter/unicode_escape_sequence_converter.php):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "( \u0361\u00b0 \u035c\u0296 \u0361\u00b0)\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the program returned the same result as before.

My end goal is to make a program that can copy a unicode string to the Windows clipboard, so if a different data-type to `string` is required, and it isn't as simple as adding some data/signature to the beginning of the string to indicate it's unicode, I'm not even sure if I can adapt this clipboard writing code to support unicode:

```
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

void clip(std::string input);

int main()
{
    clip("( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)");
    return 0;
}

void clip(std::string input)
{
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, strlen(input.c_str()) + 1);

    memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), input.c_str(), strlen(input.c_str()) + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

Notes:

- I am developing this program on Windows 10.
- On my system, `conhost.exe` (the Windows console) can handle the unicode string in question.
- I am using Code::Blocks with MinGW Compiler.

Comment: see also this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/4603670) in addition to the answer below

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That link isn't helpful for me, I'm using codeblocks instead of Visual Studio and the code provided in that answer for printing unicode won't compile for me.

Comment: Then ask a different question and mention CodeBlock/MinGW. You were asking two questions here. Copying should work with MingGW, but printing unicode is different.

Comment: By the way, it might not be possible to do that. I just tried it with Visual Studio, it doesn't do it exactly right (the solution I suggested doesn't always work). I used WriteConsoleW with CodeBlock, it didn't work as I expected. Console window has limited Unicode support.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I was originally attempting to print it so I didn't have to keep pasting after the program ran.

Comment: @L.F. I have fixed it, but is `std::string` correct?

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 Yes.  Also, use `\n` instead of `endl`.

Comment: @L.F. I here that "\n" is faster but doesn't flush the buffer. Would there be a disadvantage to not flushing the buffer (like memory filling up if there is a lot of output)? I've edited my question anyway.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 No, not at all.  Speaking of performance, `endl` is strictly inferior to `\n` from a unless the buffer needs to be flushed.  There is no such thing as "memory filling up" because the buffer knows when to flush automatically :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CF_UNICODETEXT`, not just `CF_TEXT`. Moreover, you should declare unicode string with `L` prefix, e.g. `L""`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring str(L"( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)");
    if (OpenClipboard(HWND_DESKTOP)) {
        EmptyClipboard();
        auto sz = (str.size() + 1) * sizeof(str[0]);
        auto hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, sz);
        if (hMem != nullptr) {
            auto pMem = GlobalLock(hMem);
            memcpy(pMem, str.c_str(), sz);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hMem);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate memory");
        }
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open clipboard");
    }
    return 0;
}
```