# Unicode characters not displaying correctly in command prompt on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, unicode, cmd, codepages

I recently started to work with c programming and i want to use unicode, but it's not displaying correctly in output console. i set code page to 65001 and i tried with consolas font and lucida console. but all i can see is a square with a dot in it. And it shows that for everything (except ascii characters) i paste in. But i made a small test. I named a batch file with a unicode character ( ✓ ) and pasted that in console and it showed the square character but i pressed enter and it run that batch file so it means its just not displaying it correctly.

Update:

I found out it works with Git bash shell for windows so i will stick with that until i find solution for windows command prompt or powershell.

Clarification:
I see that my question is marked as duplicate so i added this clarification, I know how to output characters in unicode but my problem is that they are not displaying correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

Comment: You'll need to find a fixed-pitch font that supports the character.  Consolas and Lucida Sans don't, as you found out.  Crystal ball says that you have Dejavu, [register it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) so it is available in a regular console window as well.  The Windows Charmap.exe applet is quite useful to see what you can use.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, so it was actually a problem with fonts. Microsoft should make more support for unicode.