# How to really print EURO sign in c++ application console in Windows

Tags: c++, console, output, cout

My target is to print euro sign - € in c++ application in Windows. Methods that already tried and did not working are:

```
#include <windows.h>
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
cout << "\u20a0";
```

also  `"\u20a0"` did not working and without `SetConsoleOutputCP()`. No working solution by far. So much forums and questions, and no straight answer....

Comment: Possibly useful: [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/583833)

Comment: [Does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not a useful problem description.

Comment: your links did not answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
cout << (char)(128);
```

Comment: Alternatively: `cout << "\x80";` Alternatively, look at `WideCharToMultiByte()`