# How to display Vietnamese characters in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, locale

So I'm currently learning C++11 and I'm getting the hang of it. I want to play around with using a different language and since I'm Vietnamese, I want to make a C++ program that uses Vietnamese characters.

So how can I display Vietnamese characters the same way that English is displayed, which is like this:

```
cout << "Hello. This is English" << endl; //English
cout << "Chào. Đây là tiếng Việt." << endl; //Vietnamese
```

I heard that C++ has `<locale>`. Does it help make the Vietnamese characters appear?

Comment: Your question doesn't say what problem you're running into...?

Comment: You need to use `wcout` etc. Look up wide characters/strings

Comment: `#include <clocale>`, `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`, `std::wcout << L"Chào. Đây là tiếng Việt."` .. works on all platforms .. but what system are you on? Windows might not display the characters without the language pack installed; this code works great on one of my Linux boxes with a bunch of locales installed, but my BSD displays only what it can because it does _not_ have the local installed ..

Comment: @nikau6 .. how so? That exact code worked as expected on my Windows system ..

Comment: @txtechhelp This character 'ế' cannot be displayed correctly.

Comment: @txtechhelp No, in fact the problem with the character  'ế' is with the 2 answers. With yours I get the output : "Chào. Đây là ti", nothing more.

Comment: Just overflow a buffer or two, perform some output and with any luck,  Vietnamese glyphs will aappear.

Comment: @jtbandes this isn't a debugging question.

Comment: It depends on your OS and compiler.

Comment: @nikau6 if you can see it in your browser, try to copy and paste it to your terminal. Can you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

Answer (score 8):

You may be running into a problem with your environment.  You don't say what platform/environment you are running in, but take the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::cout << u8"Chào thế giới!" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This yields the following output from iTerm on Mac OS X:
`Chào thế giới!`

With other (non-unicode) environments, using the same code, you may get UTF-8 characters interpreted as ASCII on output.  I don't know what the Windows command line will yield, but if you are using an IDE, your IDE may or may not render UTF-8, independently of whether your shell does or doesn't.

Here's a web example.

https://code.sololearn.com/c39N9RN6b4Md/#cpp yields:
`Ch├áo thß║┐ giß╗¢i!`

But http://ideone.com/OkkUZs running exactly the same code yields:
`Chào thế giới!`

It's probably also worth pointing out that in C++ to properly process UTF-8 strings, count "characters", ensure your strings are valid UTF-8, etc. you will likely want to use a Unicode library--working with Unicode is non-trivial.

Personally, I have found both [UTFCPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp) and [TinyUTF8](https://github.com/DuffsDevice/tinyutf8) to be excellent libraries - reasonably small, simple and effective.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 16.10 tried) also has a default UTF8 console.

Comment: Just the way it should be, IMHO. :)  Because http://utf8everywhere.org.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
     std::wcout << L"Chào. Đây là tiếng Việt.";
}
```

This is a solution that works for windows. Unfortunately it's not portable to other platforms.

Comment: This doesn't work on my system, but perhaps that's a police issue. I cannot display the character : `ế`, does it work for you? My solution has the same problem.

Comment: Yes it is displayed properly. What do you get instead?

Comment: The irony is that your unportable code is also not needed on most other platforms. Can't you set the output to UTF8 though?