# Getting a '?' in the Output when printing special (Extended) ASCII characters using `std::cout`

Tags: c++, std

I want to print extended ascii characters in console, I tried this:

```
    std::cout << "╔══════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗\n";
    std::cout << "║  ID:678  ║  Name: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓        ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  Surname: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  Gender: ▓▓▓▓▓▓                                        ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  Age: ▓▓▓                                              ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  Tel: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓                  ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  Adress: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║ ID Print ║  Hobbies: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║          ║  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║  ░░░░░░  ║  Additional İnformations: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║  ▒▓▓▓▓▒  ║  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "║  ▓▓▓▓▓▓  ║  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     ║\n";
    std::cout << "╚══════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝\n";
```

but output is like this:

```
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
?  ID:678  ?  Name: ????????????????????????????????????????        ?
?          ?  Surname: ????????????????????????????????????????     ?
?          ?  Gender: ??????                                        ?
?          ?  Age: ???                                              ?
?          ?  Tel: ???????????????????????????????                  ?
?          ?  Adress: ?????????????????????????????????????????     ?
?          ?  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????     ?
? ID Print ?  Hobbies: ????????????????????????????????????????     ?
?          ?  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????     ?
?  ??????  ?  Additional ¦nformations: ????????????????????????     ?
?  ??????  ?  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????     ?
?  ??????  ?  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????     ?
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

But when i try this: `std::cout << char(200);` it successfully print '╔' character. so i'm sure Console supports extended ascii characters.

So; how can i output these cout's correctly?

Edit: using `std::wcout << L"";` isn't working.

Edit2: Program will only run in Windows 7 or later.

Edit3:

Using this code prints card out,

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

But then, I can't print any normal cout characters, it gives error.
(example error string: `std::cout << "Hello!"` )

Comment: those characters depends on the codepage. Use Unicode instead [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714), [How do I print Unicode to the output console in C with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46512441/995714)

Comment: It's relevant to include in your post the environment where you use the code.

Comment: @anastaciu Edit2, added. It's only windows.

Comment: @AhmetYusufYatkın, it's kind of implied when you use `L` prefix, but it's better to specify it, so well done, as for the last part of your post, you need to keep using `wcout`, `std::wcout << L"Hello!";` or reset the encoding when you want to use `cout` again  `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);`.

Comment: @anastaciu thank you very much, I answered my own question while you write this. but your answer was excatly what i want.

Comment: Data point:  worked on my machine (macOS), using UTF-8, without doing anything special.  (My **vim** editor defaults to UFT-8 without BOM.)  I don't think Windows Console works with UTF-8, but (as per Ahmet's findings & answer) is able to work with UTF-16 using wcout.  There is probably a way to plumb up std::cout to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 and forward the output to std::wcout, for convenience... but that'd be an experiment for another day.

Answer (score 1):

For guys who wrote on windows, can apply this: source([_setmode Windows source](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019))

Needed Libraries:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
```

To transform cout to Unicode:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

*Important Note: in this style, you always supposed to be use std::**w**cout << L""; for this. if your code includes std::cout in other lines, here is the solution:

use `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);` to set stdout back to default text style, when you don't need special characters to print.