# Using UTF-16 for I/O with Visual Studio instead of code pages

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, utf-16, console-output

I have this working on Visual Studio 2019 using code pages:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    UINT oldcp = GetConsoleOutputCP();  
    SetConsoleOutputCP(932);      //932 = Japanese. 
                                  //1200 for little-, 1201 big-, endian UTF-16     

    DWORD used;
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),L"私の犬\n", 4,&used, 0);

    std::cout << "Hit enter to end."; std::cin.get();
    SetConsoleOutputCP(oldcp); 
    return 0;
}
```

But I am seeing from Microsoft that I [should not be using code pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages) except to interface with legacy code -- use UTF-16 instead. I can find code pages for UTF-16 (little endian or big endian), but using them doesn't work *and* it's still using code pages.

So what can I use that accomplishes what my program does, but is up-to-date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print Unicode to the output console in C with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512441/how-do-i-print-unicode-to-the-output-console-in-c-with-visual-studio)

Comment: Alas, no, those solutions were able to produce output that could be saved in a text file and displayed later (as I can, too), but not that will be visible in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Set stdin and stdout to wide mode in Windows and use `wcout` and `wcin` with wide strings.  You'll need to switch to a console font to support the characters and and IME to type them as well, which can be accomplished by installing the appropriate language support.  You're getting that switch automatically by setting a code page, but the characters output correctly even in the "wrong" code page.  If you select a font that supports the characters it will work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);

    std::wcout << L"私の犬" << std::endl;
    std::wstring a;
    std::wcout << L"Type a string: ";
    std::getline(std::wcin, a);
    std::wcout << a << std::endl;
    getwchar();
}
```

Output (terminal using code page 437 but NSimSun font):

```
私の犬
Type a string: 马克
马克
```

Comment: I would like something that would work for users who aren't dedicated enough to install different IME's, but if this is along the way to that, great. When I ran this, I got little question-mark-in-a-box characters instead of the correct ones (私の犬). This may be because I don't know how to  switch to a console font to support the characters. Can that be done in the code? Tx.

Comment: @TopologicalSort To be clear, IME is for input, not output.  You can also copy/paste chars that you cannot type, due to missing IME.  Regarding "little question-mark-in-a-box characters", you need a font that can display these chars.  What exactly is meant by "console"?  Console in MS Visual Studio?  Or a compiled binary running from cmd.exe?  If IDE, please try again from cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Technically *every character encoding is a code page*. To use UTF-16 you still have to specify the UTF-16 "code page". But you also need to **`_setmode`** first

- [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714)
- [How do I print Unicode to the output console in C with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46512441/995714)

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
std::cout << L"私の犬\n";
```

But *is it up-to-date*? **No!!!** The most reasonable way to print Unicode is to use the UTF-8 code page which will make your app cross-platform and is easier to maintain. See [What is the Windows equivalent for en_US.UTF-8 locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/995714) for details on this. Basically just

- target Windows SDK v17134 or newer, or use ***static linking*** to work on older Windows versions
- change the code page to UTF-8
- use the `-A` Win32 APIs instead of `-W` ones if you're calling those directly ([recommended by MS for portability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page#-a-vs--w-apis), as everyone else was using UTF-8 for decades)
- set the `/execution-charset:utf-8` and/or `/utf-8` flags while compiling

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF8");
std::cout << "私の犬\n";
```

See also [Is it possible to set "locale" of a Windows application to UTF-8?](https://superuser.com/q/1033088/241386)

Comment: I don't know what Windows SDK version I have; VS just says "Windows 10 (latest version available)" -- I tried a few web pages' answers, but they do not return an answer. I'll assume "change the code page to UTF-8" is the `setlocale` cmd you provided. How do I use the -A WIn32 APIs, or set the /utf-8 flag? I searched under Command-line options for compilation and linking, but couldn't find -A or utf. Tx.

Comment: You can check the Windows sdk versions  installed through the Visual  Studio installer.

Comment: @TopologicalSort please read the above links to know how to use UTF-8 locale. The `-A` APIs is simply the ones ending with A. There are almost always 2 functions for each API, one for ANSI (`-A`) and the other for Unicode (Wide, ending with `-W`), for example `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW`

Comment: In case this answer turns out to be the solution: to check Windows sdk version, open Visual Studio Installer. Click Modify on the version being used. Under Individual Components tab, search for Windows SDK.