# Print unicode and text values of char pointer

Tags: c++, unicode, char-pointer

I am new to c++, I am trying to print some values on console.
I am using below code for this

```
std::cout  << "text : " << text.latin1().data() <<endl;
```

`text.latin1().data()` returns a `char*` to me.
It works fine as long as values are normal ASCII but it prints "?" for special characters like alpha, beta and gamma (may be for utf-8).

text is WTF::String
latin1 is WTF::CString
and data is char*

How can I get the unicode values for the given `char*` and print their string values instead of "?".
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app

Comment: What is the type of the variable `text`?

Comment: This is unanswerable without further details. But it seems to me that if you are asking for a Latin1 encoding then you shouldn't be surprised when your non-Latin1 characters are lost.

Comment: `latin1()` is not a part of C++. Are you using a third party text processing library? Which one?

Comment: @n.m.  latin1() method returns WTF::CString

Comment: @RSahu text is WTF::String

Comment: @PavanTiwari, I have never used `WTF::String`. Hopefully someone else can find a satisfactory answer for you. Good luck.

Comment: @RSahu eventually i am getting char* from the method call, so you might have used char* ,so is there any way to print unicode from char*.

Comment: You'll probably need to do something with `std::wcout`; I don't think you can print unicode chars with `std::cout`

Comment: @Justin I have tried both but none of them are working for me

Comment: @PavanTiwari, Not all unicode characters can be represented by a `char`. Unless `WTF::String` has the ability to return a unicode character given an index, you might be stuck. But then, I am guessing. There might be ways that I am not aware of since I have not used `WTF::String`.

Comment: WTF is WTF? sorry, this had to be asked.

Comment: If you were to call `text.containsOnlyLatin1()`, you'll see that it returns `false`

Comment: @n.m. https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WTF/wtf/text/WTFString.cpp link for WTF:STRING i am working on phantomjs code base

Comment: @Justin https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WTF/wtf/text/WTFString.cpp code of WTF:String

Comment: "new to c++" "webkit" I don't think this is a winning combo, but what do I know. C++ doesn't support Unicode well. There is no standard way to print Unicode on the console and make it readable. On Linux this usually just works when you use UTF-8, possibly unless you are root, or on something old, or on something embedded, or on something proprietary, in which case good luck. On Windows, just good luck, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::wcout << L"text : " << text.characters() << wendl;
```

Does it work ? If not what's the compiler error message ?