# C++ string to wstring prints out incorrectly, cant get unicode path

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR;

template <typename Facet>
struct deletable_facet : Facet
{
    using Facet::Facet;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    //std::wcout << converter.from_bytes(argv[0]) << std::endl; // range error


    std::wstring_convert<deletable_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>> conv;
    std::wstring ns = conv.from_bytes(argv[0]);
    std::wcout << ns << std::endl;

    wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
    //GetModuleFileName(NULL,filename,MAX_PATH); // cant convert wstring_t* to char*
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL,filename,MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << filename << std::endl;


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 C:\Users\luka\Desktop\ⁿ?icΣ\unicode.exe
 C:\Users\luka\Desktop\ⁿ?icΣ\unicode.exe
 C:\Users\luka\Desktop\ⁿ
```

Actual name of the folder is üлicä

Ive been trying many many different ways for about 2 hours now, and as far as ive seen people suggested GetModuleFileName , but as you can see that returns a conversion error (typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR; isnt fixing it).

So is there any way to to get the current folder path in unicode , and get the rest of the input arguments to unicode (non-latin characters)

Comment: Are you writing to a file or to a terminal?

Comment: cmd, but when i cd to the folder its displayed correctly so that shouldnt be a problem unless it only shows c++ unicode incorrectly

Comment: tho when i do  std::wcout<<L"üлicä"<<std::endl; it displays ⁿ, and when i add some text eg L"areüлicä" it displays areⁿ

Comment: Windows doesn't support UTF-8 in `argv` , so taking an argv element and pretending it's a UTF-8 string simply won't work. If you are programming for Windows, your best bet is probably to use `wmain` and `wchar_t** argv`.

Comment: wmain results in undefined reference to WinMain

Comment: C:/MinGW/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you are using a Microsoft compiler, use `wmain` according to Mucrosoft documentation. It is not as simple as replacing `main`, you also need to change your project settings. I have no idea how mingw copes with this problem, you probably want to consult mingw documentation. Google for "mingw unicode" or something. You might find something like [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/), or perhaps something else.

Answer (score 1):

The usage for `GetModuleFileName` is correct. You should see the expected result with `MessageBoxW(0, filename, 0, 0);`

The problem is in printing `L"üлicä"` on Windows console.

Try printing `"üлicä"` on the console:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DWORD count;
    std::wstring str = GetCommandLineW() + (std::wstring)L"\n";
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str.c_str(), str.size(), &count, 0);
    MessageBoxW(0, str.c_str(), 0, 0);

    wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(0, filename, MAX_PATH);
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), filename, wcslen(filename), &count, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio you can also use [`_setmode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app/9051543#9051543) to enable usage of `std::wcout/std::wcin`

You also have optional entry point `wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])` which provides `argv` in UTF16 encoding.

The `main` entry point provides `argv` in ANSI encoding (not UTF8 encoding). ANSI can loose information, unlike Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is related not to the program but the console, I suggest you try to output into a file and check if the encoding is correct.

You can do that using `freopen`:

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    freopen("output-file-name.txt", "w", stdout);
    /*rest of code*/
    }`

If problem persists, try using visual studio along with `_setmode(..., _O_U16TEXT)` just before using `wcout` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/9541897

Comment: How do i use freopen("output-file-name.txt", "w", stdout); ? Is it supposed to print all the previous couts or do i pass it a wstring somewhere? And do i need to close it?

Comment: Just add it right below `int main(){`.

`int main(){
    freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
    /*rest of code
    */
}`

Comment: File is empty. here is the code:

``

         int main(int argc, char* argv[])
         {
          std::wcout << L"English -- Ελληνικά -- Español." << std::endl;
          freopen("output-file-name.txt", "w", stdout);
   std::wcout<<L"areüлicä"<<std::endl;
          }

``

Comment: I know this sounds weird but when I commented out the first `wcout` line and removed the `L` it just worked perfectly!!

Try using this code: `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { freopen("output-file-name.txt", "w", stdout); std::wcout<<"üлicä areüлicä"<<std::endl; }`

Comment: That actually saves nicely so maybe there is hope

Comment: wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileNameW(NULL,filename,MAX_PATH);
 std::wcout << filename << std::endl;

still saves just the first one tho

Comment: This leaves us with two possible scenarios, either `filename` already contain an invalid format, or it does have the correct format but `wcout` treats it in a wrong way.
Please check using visual studio and `_setmode(..., _O_U16TEXT)` right before using `wcout`, this would verify whether `wcout` is faulty

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works with Windows.  You'll have to find the right compiler/linker settings to support wmain on MinGW, but it will work.  `_setmode` enables writing Unicode directly to the terminal, and should work as long as the font supports the characters.  In my example I use some Chinese, which my font supports:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "io.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << argv[0] << std::endl;

    wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL,filename,MAX_PATH);
    std::wcout << filename << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
马克.exe
C:\üлicä\马克.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you typedefing `LPWSTR` and `PWSTR` manually? `windows.h` already handles that for you.

In any case, as @n.m. said in comments, the arguments for `main()` are NOT encoded in UTF-8 on Windows, so converting non-ASCII characters using a UTF8->UTF16 converter will not produce the correct output. Use the Win32 [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) function instead to convert the arguments, using `CP_ACP` as the codepage to convert from. Or, use `wmain()` instead, which provides arguments as `wchar_t*` instead of as `char*`.

That will get you the data you want.  Then, you just need to deal with the issue of Unicode output to the console.  As other answers point out, the Windows console does not support UTF-16 output via `std::wcout` by default, so you have to jump through some additional hoops to make it work correctly (there are many other questions on StackOverflow about that issue).