# How can I get a Unicode character from a number?

Tags: c++, unicode, console-output

I'm new to C++, so sorry if this is obvious.

How can I get a character from a number?
I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    cout << i;
}
```

It's supposed to get the first 500 characters in the Unicode dictionary.
I know that in javascript, it is `String.fromCodePoint(i)`. What's the C++ equivalent?

Comment: Did you try `(char)i`? It won't do Unicode. C++ doesn't really know about Unicode.

Comment: @user253751 it's not true. C++ isn't entirely Unicode-friendly, but it does have Unicode char and string types (`char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` and their corresponding `std::u8string`, `std::u32string` and `std::u32string`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wchar_t` instead

```
for (wchar_t i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    wcout << i;
}
```

You can also use [`char16_t` and `char32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) if you're using C++11 or newer

However you still need a capable terminal and also need to set the correct codepage to get the expected output. On Linux it's quite straight forward but if you're using (an older) Windows it's much trickier. See [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714)

Comment: `wchar_t` is not Unicode, nor is it required to be interpreted as Unicode.

Comment: @NicolBolas fair enough. But in practice it's UTF-16 on Windows and UTF-32 everywhere else. Besides **`char16_t` and `char32_t` are required to be UTF-16 and UTF-32 respectively**

Comment: Don't you want to use [`wcout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) instead?

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, I forgot that. Thanks. Anyway I think std::cout on Windows has specializations for wchar_t

Comment: @phuclv "*I think std::cout on Windows has specializations for wchar_t*" - no, it doesn't. That is why `std::wcin`/`std::wcout`/`std::wcerr` exist, to handle `wchar_t`.  `std::cin`/`std::cout`/`std::cerr` handle `char` only.