# How get a local time with same time format on windows?

Tags: c++, localtime

I have a c++ class code which return a local time:

```
SYSTEMTIME sm;
GetLocalTime( &sm );
```

but sm.wHour always returns an hour in 24 format, it doesn't concern my windows os time format settings!! (ie. use 24 or 12 time format).

How can I get a local time hour according to my windows os time format settings?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformata) helping?

Comment: @LouisGo no, doesn't work

Comment: Any answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found `GetDateFormatA` is outdated, you should use `GetDateFormatEx`

Simple example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    const int len = 50;
    LPWSTR date = new WCHAR[len];
    GetDateFormatEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_AUTOLAYOUT, NULL, NULL, date, len, NULL);

    LPWSTR time = new WCHAR[len];
    GetTimeFormatEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, time, len );

    std::wcout << date << std::endl << time;
    return 0;
}
```

If you have question about the api parameters, you may find [GetDateFormatEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformatex) and [GetTimeFormatEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-gettimeformatex)  in msdn are useful.

For `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`, it's a hack to print unicode under windows console.
You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/4123703)

Note WinApis above depend on [long time format](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10), not short time format.

Though I couldn't find api for short time format. If you want a time format no including seconds, use `TIME_NOSECONDS` instead of `LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT`.

Comment: I have tested this code and this always display in 12 time format even I change my time settings OS to 24 format

Comment: @BassamNajeeb There are two kind of DateTime format in windows. One is short and another is long. After I tested, GetTimeFormatEx depends on long format. If you're win10, refer to this [link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10) to change format.

Comment: thanks, it works right with long format, any way run it with short format settings ?

Comment: I did not found any related topic about it. You may post your answer if you found it. Though I'd suggest to take a step back asking "why short time format is needed?" If long time format is too long, passing `TIME_NOMINUTESORSECONDS` would get you a string without seconds.

Comment: My problem is a Windows OS take a time format from a "short time format" option, and a user see a side effect of this option at a right corner of a task bar, so I want from my software also take this option rather than a long time format, i.e make it a single option and be an identical to Win OS.

Comment: @BassamNajeeb Your best shot is getting registry of `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sShortTime` for string format.