# Visual Studio C++ outputting �� instead of 汉字?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-10, unicode-string

I am trying to print out the string 汉字 in Visual Studio 2019 C++.
Something I think I should say is probably, I'm on Windows 10 and I have been trying to figure this out using the internet for an hour to no prevail.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::wstring myWString = L"汉字"; // Tried a wstring, didn't output anything
    std::string myString = "汉字"; // Tried using a normal string, it outputted the �'s
    std::wcout << myWString << std::endl;
    std::cout << myString << std::endl;
}
```

In the projects properties, I added `/source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8` to the additional options in Command Line under C/C++, and I also checked `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.` in my region settings. So why can't I print out these characters, and is this fixable, if so how?

Fixed: I went to my registry editor into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method`, added a new value named EnableHexNumpad and set the data to '1'. After that I restarted my PC and it worked.

Comment: This might be because of the font used by the console.

Comment: You can't store `"汉字"` as-is into a `std::string`, you would need to encode it to UTF-8 first, eg: `u8"汉字"`. And your console would have to be configured to print out UTF-8.

Comment: Well then I am not sure why storing 汉字 into a normal string then printing it out worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This question is similar to yours.
Browse through the answers, there's one with printing out 你好.
[Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)
(I would like to comment on your question, but my low reputation score does not allow me to do that, So I'm sorry to create an Answer comment.)

Comment: no, that's very old. New Windows 10 SDKs supports UTF-8 as a locale so no need to use UTF-16 like that anymore

Comment: @phuclv except that you need to manually opt-in to that new SDK behavior, you don't get it for free. And that is assuming the new behavior is even enabled by the user to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know that. The OP already knows some UTF-8 related-options so just some more things will make it work