# Windows 1250 or UTF-8 in MS Visual Studio?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

Here I have a simple, exemplary code in MS Visual Studio:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << static_cast<int>('ą') << endl; // -71
   return 0;
}
```

The question is why this cout prints out -71 as if MS Visual Studio was using Windows 1250 if as far as I know it uses UTF-8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is saved in Windows-1250, not UTF-8, so the *byte* stored between the two single quotes is 0xB9 (see [Windows-1250 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)).  0xB9 taken as a signed 8-bit value is -71.

Save your file in UTF-8 encoding and you'll get a different answer.  I get 50309 which is 0xc485.  since UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding, it would be better to use modern C++ to output the bytes of an explicit UTF-8 string, use UTF-8 source encoding, and tell the compiler explicitly that the source encoding it UTF-8:

test.c - saved in UTF-8 encoding and compiled with `/utf-8` switch in MSVS:

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s {u8"ą马"};
    for(auto c : s)
        cout << hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<uint8_t>(c)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c4
85
e9
a9
ac
```

Note `C4 85` is the correct UTF-8 bytes for `ą` and `E9 A9 AC` are correct for Chinese 马 (horse).