# Modify font size when print out to screen

Tags: python, windows, cmd, font-size, command-prompt

I'm using Win XP and Python 2.5. Is there a way in Python to modify font size when print to CMD window?

Comment: Python knows nothing about the font: that's entirely down to Windows. Look for any options in the command prompt window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change console font in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592673/change-console-font-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ctypes` to access the necessary windows calls to change the font (including the size of the font) of the console. See my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592673/change-console-font-in-windows/13940780#13940780) for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a desktop link to cmd.exe and set/change the layout properties (e.g. to window size 120*40 or appropriate). Start your program in this console windows (python.exe yourprogram.py).

Answer (score -4):

No, you can't change that, as far as I know. Luckly, nobody on windows uses the console anyway, so I advise you to move to a GUI library instead.

With your own GUI window, you can configure the font and layout as much as you want, include buttons, images, animations, menus, etc...

Comment: "... nobody on windows uses the console anyway ..." - Hogwash!    I use it, most programmers and other technical people I know who have to use Windows use it.  I've even trained my (non-technical) wife to use it at times.  Granted, the fraction of people who use it may be small ...

Comment: @GreenMatt: Well, you're a programmer. If I had to use windows I'd install cygwin or something to have a real terminal. Windows console sucks - you have to admit it - it doesn't make a good tool and is more annoying than useful

Comment: Granted, it's not the best, and I have Cygwin on my own systems.  However, I generally don't have it available on systems belonging to family members, friends, etc.  Also, some workplaces lock down their systems and won't install Cygwin.  :-(

Comment: @GreenMatt: You mean you often want to run your python code on a console window at your family member's computer? Come on, if that's the case, then building a GUI isn't that hard.