# Change Linux terminal font type using python

Tags: python, linux, fonts

is it possible to switch the font type for the Linux terminal using python 3? There are threads about the windows console:

[Change console font in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592673/change-console-font-in-windows)

I try to build an application which runs on standard Linux terminals like Xfce or gnome terminal or terminator for example. Changing text color and background is easy. But for switching the font type I found no solution. 
I think I could write a script that defines terminal layout at startup, but that wouldn't run for different terminals. Terminator has it's own config files and other terminals, too.

Comment: The terminal has no concept of what font it's using, just its dimensions.  The font choice is up to the user.

Comment: Terminal font is not part of the POSIX standard. So each terminal emulator can handle it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link helps you[1](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting). It shows several ways of coloring your shell. So you can but this in the call of your shell from python.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I know there are several modules to change color. I already thought it wouldn't be possible to change font out of python. So maybe I write a few start scripts for the standard terminals which opens it with Special configs an run my application.