# Python Programmatically Change Console font size

Tags: python, cmd, fonts, ctypes

I found the code below which is supposed to programmatically change the console font size. I'm on Windows 10.

However, whatever values I tweak, I can't seem to get any control over the font size, and also for some reason the console which gets opened when I run this script is very wide.

I have no idea how ctypes works - all I want is to modify the size of the console font from inside Python.

Any actual working solutions?

```
import ctypes

LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]

font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
font.nFont = 12
font.dwFontSize.X = 11
font.dwFontSize.Y = 18
font.FontFamily = 54
font.FontWeight = 400
font.FaceName = "Lucida Console"

handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))


print("Foo")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before everything, check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions).

The *CTypes* home page (also listed in the above *URL*): [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)

I changed your code "a bit".

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import ctypes.wintypes as wts
import sys


LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11


class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("cbSize", wts.ULONG),
        ("nFont", wts.DWORD),
        ("dwFontSize", wts._COORD),
        ("FontFamily", wts.UINT),
        ("FontWeight", wts.UINT),
        ("FaceName", wts.WCHAR * LF_FACESIZE)
    )


def main(*argv):
    kernel32 = cts.WinDLL("Kernel32.dll")

    GetLastError = kernel32.GetLastError
    GetLastError.argtypes = ()
    GetLastError.restype = wts.DWORD

    GetStdHandle = kernel32.GetStdHandle
    GetStdHandle.argtypes = (wts.DWORD,)
    GetStdHandle.restype = wts.HANDLE

    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx = kernel32.GetCurrentConsoleFontEx
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx.argtypes = (wts.HANDLE, wts.BOOL, cts.POINTER(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX))
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx.restype = wts.BOOL

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx = kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx.argtypes = (wts.HANDLE, wts.BOOL, cts.POINTER(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX))
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx.restype = wts.BOOL

    # Get stdout handle
    stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    if not stdout:
        print("{:s} error: {:d}".format(GetStdHandle.__name__, GetLastError()))
        return
    # Get current font characteristics
    font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
    font.cbSize = cts.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
    res = GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(stdout, False, cts.byref(font))
    if not res:
        print("{:s} error: {:d}".format(GetCurrentConsoleFontEx.__name__, GetLastError()))
        return
    # Display font information
    print("Console information for {:}".format(font))
    for field_name, _ in font._fields_:
        field_data = getattr(font, field_name)
        if field_name == "dwFontSize":
            print("    {:s}: {{X: {:d}, Y: {:d}}}".format(field_name, field_data.X, field_data.Y))
        else:
            print("    {:s}: {:}".format(field_name, field_data))
    while 1:
        try:
            height = int(input("\nEnter font height (invalid to exit): "))
        except:
            break
        # Alter font height
        font.dwFontSize.X = 10  # Changing X has no effect (at least on my machine)
        font.dwFontSize.Y = height
        # Display font information
        res = SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(stdout, False, cts.byref(font))
        if not res:
            print("{:s} error: {:d}".format(SetCurrentConsoleFontEx.__name__, GetLastError()))
            return
        print("OMG! The window changed :)")
        # Get current font characteristics again
        res = GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(stdout, False, cts.byref(font))
        if not res:
            print("{:s} error: {:d}".format(GetCurrentConsoleFontEx.__name__, GetLastError()))
            return
        print("\nNew sizes    X: {:d}, Y: {:d}".format(font.dwFontSize.X, font.dwFontSize.Y))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- *CTypes* allows low level access similar to *C* (only the syntax is *Python*)
- Code uses [[MS.Learn]: SetConsoleTextAttribute function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute)

  - In order to avoid setting invalid values, it's used in conjunction with its counterpart: [[MS.Learn]: GetCurrentConsoleFontEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getcurrentconsolefontex). Call that function in order to populate the *CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX* structure, then modify only the desired values
  - There are "simpler" functions (e.g. [[MS.Learn]: GetCurrentConsoleFont function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getcurrentconsolefont) or [[MS.Learn]: GetConsoleFontSize function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolefontsize)), but unfortunately there are no corresponding setters
  - **Note that all referenced *WinAPI* functions are deprecated**
- The *ctypes.wintypes* constants (which reference the standard *CTypes* types) are used (to give the code a *Win* like flavor)
- It is very (almost painfully) long (also because I've added proper error handling)
- An alternative, as suggested in one of the answers of [[SO]: Change console font in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592673/4788546) (where you copied the code from), would be to install a 3<sup>rd</sup>-party module (e.g. [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) which is a *Python* wrapper over *WINAPI*s) which would require less code to write because the bridging between *Python* and *C* would be already implemented, and probably the above functionality could be accomplished in just a few lines
- As I commented in the code, setting *COORD.X* seems to be ignored. But it's automatically set when setting *COORD.Y* (to a value close to `COORD.Y // 2` - probably to preserve the aspect ratio). On my machine (*Win 10 pc064*) with the currently selected font, the default value is ***16***. You might want to set it back at the end, to avoid leaving the console in a "challenged" state (apparently, *Win* adjusts *Cmd* window size, to be (sort of) in *sync* with the font size):

[image: Img0]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pure python problem, but covers Windows API.

Look at the documentation of [CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-font-infoex) structure. There is a [COORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/coord-str) member on it for width and height of each character.

To change console font size, you can give these attributes as a proper value:

```
font.dwFontSize.X = 11
font.dwFontSize.Y = 18
```

Reference: [Change console font in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592673/change-console-font-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future who wants to use the console as a method of displaying (black and white) images or just getting the smallest possible font size, this is the modified answer code I used. I found a height and width of 2px was the best smallest size, but be cautious, all sizes distort the picture, some more than others. As the font, I use the only "rasterfont" that's available. (Personally I had massive problems getting this to work, not sure why tho... and this is NOT the same as the accepted answer)

```
def changeFontSize(size=2): #Changes the font size to *size* pixels (kind of, but not really. You'll have to try it to chack if it works for your purpose ;) )
    from ctypes import POINTER, WinDLL, Structure, sizeof, byref
    from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, SHORT, WCHAR, UINT, ULONG, DWORD, HANDLE

    LF_FACESIZE = 32
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

    class COORD(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("X", SHORT),
            ("Y", SHORT),
        ]

    class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("cbSize", ULONG),
            ("nFont", DWORD),
            ("dwFontSize", COORD),
            ("FontFamily", UINT),
            ("FontWeight", UINT),
            ("FaceName", WCHAR * LF_FACESIZE)
        ]

    kernel32_dll = WinDLL("kernel32.dll")

    get_last_error_func = kernel32_dll.GetLastError
    get_last_error_func.argtypes = []
    get_last_error_func.restype = DWORD

    get_std_handle_func = kernel32_dll.GetStdHandle
    get_std_handle_func.argtypes = [DWORD]
    get_std_handle_func.restype = HANDLE

    get_current_console_font_ex_func = kernel32_dll.GetCurrentConsoleFontEx
    get_current_console_font_ex_func.argtypes = [HANDLE, BOOL, POINTER(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)]
    get_current_console_font_ex_func.restype = BOOL

    set_current_console_font_ex_func = kernel32_dll.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx
    set_current_console_font_ex_func.argtypes = [HANDLE, BOOL, POINTER(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)]
    set_current_console_font_ex_func.restype = BOOL

    stdout = get_std_handle_func(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
    font.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)

    font.dwFontSize.X = size
    font.dwFontSize.Y = size

    set_current_console_font_ex_func(stdout, False, byref(font))
```