# When using CMD terminal Python can't display Hebrew

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, character-encoding, hebrew

I'm trying to use Hebrew Characters in my code. but my terminal (CMD) can't support Hebrew and instead it just displays random question marks.
For example:

```
>>>Print("דוגמא")
```

result: `?????` \

EDIT: The CMD console simply has no Hebrew letters in its default font. You can simply change the font to display Hebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution.
[Change console font in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592673/change-console-font-in-windows)
There is a code there to change the font. I found out it also works for fonts that are usually not supported by CMD.

according to the answer:

````py
import ctypes

LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]

font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
font.nFont = 12
font.dwFontSize.X = 11
font.dwFontSize.Y = 18
font.FontFamily = 54
font.FontWeight = 400
font.FaceName = "Lucida Console"

handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))```
````

Comment: It still didn't display Hebrew text for me.

Comment: @bob You can also permanently change your console settings.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work from the cmd line... at least not for me.

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica there is another solution. Use the Windows Terminal console, it's a much better alternative now, and comes with a good font.

Comment: Also I'm sorry for the bad English in the post above, I wrote it when my English skills weren't very decent.

Comment: @TheShwarma I am using VS Code terminal, which works great.

Answer (score 7):

> This will affect the Command (CMD) console.

1. Open regedit.exe and navigate to this location:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
2. Occasionally you will see two values named `0` and `00`. Add a third String Value and name it: `000` (Zero three times).
3. In this new `000` String Value, enter `Courier New` (case sensitive) in the Value Data field.
4. Now open Powershell (this work for CMD as well) and go to `properties`: Left click on top left Powershell icon and select `properties`.
5. Go to `Font` tab and select the `Courier New` font:

Now you should see Hebrew when you switch to Hebrew writing (backwards view). This enables you to send output Hebrew writing from a script for instance.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is not necessary in Python 3.

Comment: I'm using CMD. it doesnt display non-ascci characters

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there a solution without changing the registery? I mean to use this program compiled on many computers.

Comment: @TheShwarma: If the font in the terminal doesn't support Hebrew, you have to change it. There is no way reasonable way around that if you want to print to a terminal.

Comment: This worked for me for the CMD window specifically, but did not work for the Powershell; I still get ?????? instead of Hebrew characters in the PS.

Answer (score 0):

> use this for hebrew ,it should work ,it's the same code as "the shwarna " wrote above ,but you gotta replace font.FaceName = "Lucida Console" with font.FaceName = ""Hadassah Friedlaender" ,for it to work .

```
LF_FACESIZE = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]

font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
font.nFont = 12
font.dwFontSize.X = 11
font.dwFontSize.Y = 18
font.FontFamily = 54
font.FontWeight = 300
font.FaceName = "Hadassah Friedlaender"

handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))
```