# Changing the Font of the Python Console Programmatically

Tags: python, fonts

Is there a way to change the font of text in the python console programmatically in repl.it?

Comment: What do you mean by python console? Do you mean IDLE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change console font in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592673/change-console-font-in-windows)

Comment: You would need to launch the console via another program with its own configs. Without knowing your development environment, it's not possible.

Comment: You can change color, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473297/how-do-i-print-colored-output-with-python-3

Comment: @Dr-Braket, is it possible to do it in repl.it?

Comment: Have you tried searching in the repl.it forums? Example: https://repl.it/talk/ask/Changing-font/24322

Answer (score 0):

You can format Python print() using termcolor and Pyfiglet

[Example](https://towardsdatascience.com/prettify-your-terminal-text-with-termcolor-and-pyfiglet-880de83fda6b)