# std::wcout strange error: truncated output of std::wstring

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm rather curious about the phenomenon, `std::wcout` can't output the whole content of `std::wstring`. Am I missing something?

Here is my output:

```
F:\
F:\
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
std::wstring ws(L"F:\\右旋不规则.pdf");
std::wcout << ws << std::endl;
std::wcout << ws.data() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Perhaps this might give you a clue: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e16148d281202045a5f3b4565c85a15b-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f

Comment: Try setup locale ( std::wcout.imbue() ), or experiment with codecvt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already several threads on this topic:

[Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

[Using Unicode font in C++ console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922294/using-unicode-font-in-c-console-app)

[Output Unicode to console Using C++, in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849010/output-unicode-to-console-using-c)

The point is you need the system to be able to display your Chinese characters (they are Chinese, right?). I don't think that the default fonts available for the console are able to do that. Lucinda Console could be used for many Unicode characters, but I don't think it's able to display Chinese. If you have a font for that, you can add it to the Console.

[How to display japanese Kanji inside a cmd window under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780378/how-to-display-japanese-kanji-inside-a-cmd-window-under-windows)

https://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-xp-console-font